# MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Com o `mysql_*` entrando no estado *deprecated*, a documentação PHP recomenda o uso do PDO  e MySQLi.

Qual vocês recomendam para o uso? PDO parece ser mais indicado para trabalhar com orientado a objetos só que ao mesmo tempo vi [*benchmarks*](http://jnrbsn.com/2010/06/mysqli-vs-pdo-benchmarks) que mostram que a performance usando o MySQLi teria uma performance maior, a performance poderia impactar muito se comparar ao uso com o PDO?

Comment: Se eu fosse dar uma resposta curta: "Depende do DB". Se é MySQL, mysqli, senão, talvez PDO, se o DB escolhido não tiver um bom suporte nativo. Mais detalhes na [resposta com fundamentação técnica linkada aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8403/70)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## MySQLi:

#### Vantagens:

- API Orientada a objetos e procedural;
- Performace elevada;
- Sintaxe relativamente mais simples (e similar a antiga API `mysql_*`);

#### Desvantagens:

- Só funciona com bancos MySQL;
- Não possui parâmetros nomeados;
- Não possui *prepared statements* do lado cliente;

---

## PDO:

#### Vantagens:

- Funciona com 12 drivers de bancos de dados diferentes (4D, MS SQL Server, Firebird/Interbase, **MySQL**, **Oracle**, ODBC/DB2, **PostgreSQL**, **SQLite**, Informix, IBM, CUBRID);
- API Orientada a objetos;
- Possui parâmetros nomeados;
- Possui *prepared statements* do lado cliente *(ver desvantagens abaixo)*

#### Desvantagens:

- Não tão veloz quanto MySQLi;
- Por padrão, ele **simula** prepared statements *(você pode ativar a versão nativa ao configurar a conexão dele com o banco, mas caso a versão nativa não funcione por algum motivo, ele volta a simular os prepared statements **sem disparar erros ou avisos**. [Mais detalhes aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919645/can-i-use-real-prepared-statements-for-mysql-with-pdo-now))*

---

Entre as duas opções eu dou preferência ao PDO, mesmo sendo um pouco mais lento (entre 2%-7%). Ao meu ver, o fato do PDO se comunicar com mais drivers de BDs e de  possuir *prepared statements*, que é de grande valia quando o assunto é segurança, na minha opinião torna esta tecnologia mais interessante.

Comment: Me parece tendenciosa a resposta quanto aos _prepared statements_, valorizando o PDO numa coisa que na verdade é desvantagem. O PDO atualmente apenas simula os _prepared statements_ , enquanto o _mysqli_ os tem nativamente, o que é fundamental para reaproveitar o trabalho do _planner_ dentro de operações repetitivas (que é a verdadeira razão de existir _prepare_). Ainda, a interface OO está disponivel no MySQLi alem do PDO, não é uma "vantagem do PDO" como colocado na lista (e ainda, não ajuda em nada pro PHP, é mera questão de sintaxe).

Answer (score 48):

Se você está preocupado com performance e não tem interesse em portabilidade, a melhor opção é sempre o mysqli.

Uma das diferenças é que com o mysqli as consultas preparadas são implementadas no lado do servidor do banco de dados, enquanto com o PDO são emuladas no lado do cliente.

Isto significa que cada vez que roda um script de PHP, com o PDO as consultas preparadas têm de ser compiladas de novo para gerar uma consulta comum não preparada e o PHP fica gastando tempo recompilando a consulta e enviando a consulta inteira para o servidor MySQL.

Já com o mysqli, o PHP apenas manda os parâmetros a cada vez que a mesma consulta preparada é enviada para o servidor quando usa a mesma conexão persistente, mesmo que esteja atendendo uma requisição HTTP diferente.

A eventual vantagem da portabilidade do PDO muitas vezes acaba sendo utópica porque a maior parte das aplicações quando optam por mysql, acabam não por não mudar nunca mais.

Comment: Excelente, principalmente sobre consultas preparadas e a "lenda" da portabilidade.

Comment: Complemento: mesmo que não sejam usadas conexões persistentes, as prepared queries do MySQLi podem ser muito úteis em operações em loop, pois somente os parâmetros serão enviados para o _query planner_ da segunda execução em diante. No PDO todo o trabalho do planner é perdido entre uma consulta e outra, mesmo nestes casos.

Answer (score 18):

<sub>Eu resolvi responder, mesmo sabendo que essa resposta nunca terá mais votos e parecerá que ela não é tão boa, porque tem havido muita informação falsa sendo espalhada por aí, as respostas não detalham e por causa da superficialidade ficam parecendo opinião, ainda que podem ser colocadas, e aí começa ter a informação falsa sendo espalhada, mesmo que não seja intencional, deixa margem para as pessoas interpretarem errado.</sub>

## Vantagens e desvantagens

A resposta aceita até está parcialmente correta nas vantagens e desvantagens, mas colocar *prepared statements* como vantagem do PDO me parece errado, pelo menos coloca nas desvantagens, ora, ou é um ou outro, e é desvantagem porque é uma simulação, como foi dito lá e isso é só ruim, pior ainda porque tenta criar a ilusão que tem algo bom. Pior que algo não existir é existir e não fazer o que se espera. Veja o [comentário do Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar#comment227576_8403).

Ela também coloca uma vantagem que pode ser mal interpretada, porque lista bancos de dados que são acessados no PDO. Sem PDO também pode acessar todos esses bancos de dados, e sempre de (quase) forma melhor (os DBs mais usados sempre é melhor), então na forma que está escrito isso nem é uma vantagem.

O que na verdade esse item quer dizer é que você pode fazer seu código acessar um banco de dados e depois trocar para outro. E de fato essa é a única vantagem real que as pessoas citam que o PDO é superficialmente melhor, o resto é firula ou é falso.

Mesmo esse caso é meio falso. Estritamente é verdadeiro, você pode fazer isto, mas é uma vantagem do tipo "tenho um umbigo e posso brincar com ele".

A primeira falsidade sobre isso e que causa outro problema é que as pessoas acham que podem e devem trocar de banco de dados facilmente assim.

Abstrações são boas, o ideal realmente é que certos aspectos da tecnologia sejam detalhes de implementação e que se um dia precisar trocar deveria poder fazê-lo facilmente. Porém essa é uma dessas regras que funcionam melhor no papel que na prática. Com banco de dados os detalhes de implementação fazem diferença no funcionamento geral e embora a troca possa permitir funcionar normalmente, na maioria dos casos, depois da troca, não quer dizer que ficará bom.

O primeiro mito sobre isso é que as pessoas trocam de banco de dados, já dito em outra resposta. Elas não fazem isso, essa troca é extremamente rara. Em geral não tem motivos técnicos para fazer a troca. E ter uma dificuldade a menos para fazer troca incentiva trocas por motivações políticas, você não quer facilitar uma decisão política mexer no seu sistema, certo?

## Escala

Em geral todos bancos de dados relacionais e operados corretamente atendem bem qualquer situação. Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL e até alguns outros funcionam bem em todas situações. Eles escalam bem em quaisquer cenários, todos eles são usados nos maiores sites do mundo sem problemas. Para isso eles são *tunados* para dar a melhor performance, o código é feito pensando neles, não é um código genérico que faz escalar bem, é o oposto, por isso o maior motivo que as pessoas acham que podem precisar trocar o banco de dados um dia, o PDO te trará problemas, porque ele já tem uma lentidão natural (nem vou falar que o PHP é lento então se o problema é a performance já escolheu a linguagem errada), ele faz você escrever um código mais genérico para um DB (ou deixar fazer um específico do mesmo jeito) e se trocar esse código não será adequado para o novo DB e escalará até pior.

Me recuso falar de ODBC, isso é ruim demais e usar PDO em cima de ODBC não faz sentido. Nos raros casos que você precise acessar um outro banco de dados de forma isolada então faça com a API nativa dele e não pelo PDO ou ODBC, só tem vantagens.

Estou tirando o SQLite aqui porque ele não escala bem em cenários de grandes escritas concorrentes, mas no resto escala muito bem, até melhor, mas tem cenários que é escolha errada, em geral onde é quase certo que terá muita escrita realmente concorrente, absolutamente raro em sites que não sejam insanamente populares, por isso até o SQLite é adequado na maioria das situações e se está tendo problemas é problema do seu código ou modelagem usada.

Então mesmo que tenha escolhido errado, em geral trocar o banco de dados não é a solução, *tunar* o que já tem é a solução. Em geral a troca só traria bons resultados em casos que a pessoa saiba muito bem o que está fazendo, e o mais comum é que pessoas com essa capacidade não fazem escolhas erradas, e se fizeram elas sabem bem que é melhor trabalhar com o que tem do que fazer a troca. Só caem nessa de trocar a tecnologia para melhorar a escala quem é ingênuo ou algum caso muito radical (do tipo 1 em milhão). Então as pessoas mais ingênuas é que escolhem o PDO. Me desculpe se não gosta disto, mas a intenção é torná-lo menos ingênuo, é fazer você evoluir o pensamento corrente.

## Novos recursos

Outro motivo que as pessoas pensam em trocar de DB é porque um outro pode fazer coisas que o atual não pode.

Primeiro vamos matar essa falácia, todos DBs de mesmo modelo podem fazer tudo, o que existe de diferente é que alguns dão uma facilidade a mais e alguns fazem melhor alguma coisa do jeito padrão. Mas todos podem fazer as mesmas coisas, então trocar não te dá uma nova capacidade.

Se você fizer a escolha por um DB logo de cara poderá aproveitar essas diferenças, se optou por outro e depois resolveu trocar não poderá usar só porque fez a troca. Até poderá se começar mexer em todo seu código. Ué, mas o PDO não era usado para não ter que mexer em todo o código? Então quem trocar porque acha que vai magicamente aproveitar os "novos recursos" está muito enganado, você já teve a dificuldade por ter escolhido errado, a troca não vai te ajudar agora, pelo contrário vai te trazer um monte de problema que você não enxerga ainda, tomará uma decisão baseada em suposições falsas.

Algumas pessoas até percebem que pra trocar o DB não podem usar todos recursos do seu DB inicial, ou seja, ela nivela por baixo o código inicial para facilitar a suposta futura troca. Poucas pessoas fazem isto, mas as que fazem geralmente erram e nivelam por baixo demais em alguns pontos e não abaixam tanto quanto seria necessário em alguns pontos, não resolvendo o problema. As pessoas são péssimas para prever o que acontecerá no futuro (a maioria erra até falando do passado :) ). E perceba que o problema que está tendo que te faz querer trocar de SGDB é justamente ter nivelado por baixo, que é uma generalização prematura.

Identificou um paradoxo aí? Para evitar ter que trocar de DB não pode pensar que um dia ele será trocado. Se pensar que um dia ele será trocado estará criando uma situação que ele precisará ser trocado, então provavelmente conseguiu uma profecia [autorrealizável](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy).

> A grama do vizinho sempre parece mais verde do outro lado da cerca

Esta é uma das coisas mais importantes que as pessoas que trabalham com TI (todo mundo na verdade) devem saber. As pessoas nunca sabem dos problemas que irão ter quando trocam de tecnologia, mesmo a conhecendo, porque nunca fez no cenário atual, e em geral, as pessoas subestimam esses problemas e superestimam a capacidade daquilo ser a solução.

O ser humano tem uma incrível incapacidade de apreciar o que está usando (mesmo que tenha defeitos que precisam ser reconhecidos) e sempre acham que indo para outro lugar, escolhendo outra coisa vai resolver todos seus problemas. Não é a mesma coisa, mas é uma forma de [efeito Duning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), ela acredita que sabe que a troca solucionará os problemas dela de forma mágica, mesmo que conscientemente ela não admita esse defeito. Isto é acreditar em Papai Noel.

O oposto também é verdade, muitas vezes as pessoas ficam em coisas que deveriam trocar, ou pelo menos ter escolhido melhor no início, e na próxima deveriam fazer uma melhor escolha, porque acha que sua grama resolve tudo (na verdade ela não quer aprender outra coisa). Mas o maior problema é que a troca não trará tanto benefício, ou se trocar terá um custo que você terá que arcar.

## Troca mágica

Este é o segundo mito.

Não estou dizendo que em todas situações você não terá vantagens se fizer a troca, só estou dizendo que as trocas não ocorrem tanto quanto as pessoas acham que ocorrem, que não compensa você piorar seu software (usando PDO) para algo que quase nunca ocorre de fato, então você cria um problema porque tem uma chance de 0,1% (número chutado) de fazer o que está esperando que vai acontecer.

Se não tivesse nenhuma desvantagem em usar o PDO eu até o recomendaria, mesmo que ele não seja tão vantajoso quanto as pessoas acham que ele é.

Acontece que para trocar o banco de dados, nos raros casos que isso trará alguma vantagem real, só acontecerá se mexer muito no código. Não é só o detalhe de implementação do banco de dados em si que terá que mexer. A forma de fazer as *queries* terá que ser trocada para ficar eficiente e ter a escala maior que está esperando, em alguns casos terá que mudar radicalmente, você terá que mexer na sua base de código toda para escalar.

Se vai usar um recurso específico desse DB terá que escrever isso, não usará esses recursos magicamente sem fazer algo. E se usou algo específico do primeiro DB escolhido não funcionará no novo, então será obrigado mexer para funcionar. Portanto se tem que mexer no código todo use a tecnologia mais simples, mais performática, mais segura e se tiver que mexer porque trocou o banco de dados, você mexe.

Alguém pode alegar que não precisaria trocar em todas partes do código, só em algumas. Isso pode ser verdade em algumas situações, mas também é verdade se usar o `mysqli`. Ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam o código usado por ele pode ser muito reaproveitado se trocar de banco de dados, pode ser apenas que terá que trocar em alguns lugares diferentes. E pra falar a verdade não deve confiar muito nisso. Se fizer a troca então deve reavaliar todas *queries*, e o maior trabalho é a avaliação, não é mudá-las.

Nem falei da remodelagem física do banco de dados. Um modelo que funciona bem em um RDBMS pode não funcionar bem em outro, então teria que mudar bastante coisa no código se mudar o modelo, e se não mudá-lo pode ser que a troca seja menos e eficiente, derrotando o propósito.

As pessoas não percebem essa dificuldade toda porque elas nunca precisaram trocar, elas falam da vantagem de poder trocar sem ver o quanto custa fazer isto e iludem as pessoas. As pessoas não estão falando de algo que elas conhecem na prática, elas falam de uma teoria que ela inventou ou copiou de outro, e aí todo mundo sai repetindo essa falácia.

Se tem algo errado e uma troca pode resolver, não é a troca do banco de dados que vai resolver, o problema é de arquitetura e terá que mexer em muito mais coisas.

## Só vale pra relacional

E se a solução nem seja continuar usando um banco de dados relacional, um DB que não está na lista do PDO? Nos raros casos que precisar mesmo trocar de DB tem grande chance que tenha que trocar o modelo e o PDO ajuda em nada, foi uma tentativa inócua de generalização.

Percebe como muita coisa precisa acontecer para ter valido a pena usar o PDO? Será que tudo irá conspirar a favor no seu caso? Vale o sacrifício por algo tão incerto?

## Benefícios da troca de tecnologia

Uma das coisas que mais a pessoa está preocupada é em escolher a tecnologia correta, entre elas a linguagem mais adequada. Neste último caso eu costumo dizer que importa pouco na maioria das situações, tem pequenas nuances que vão influenciar, mas qualquer decisão resolverá o problema dela. Umas das poucas nuances é se o software escalará bem em performance e [manutenção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90297/101), e apenas as linguagens de *scripts* são piores (elas são boas para coisas simples e pra uso individual) que as "nativas", mas é uma escolha de filosofia e não de linguagem em si.

Claro que não vai tentar fazer um sistema operacional em JavaScript (dá, já fizeram,  mas não faça) e não tem porque fazer um *backend web* em Assembly que dá, mas não faz sentido. Claro que se vai fazer uma *stored procedure* em um DB a maioria deles exige uma variação do SQL ou alguma linguagem específica por imposição da plataforma. O *browser* já impôs o uso do JS no *frontend*, mas isso não é mais verdade e em muitos casos compensa usar outra coisa (ainda que também tenha desvantagens). Fora obrigação de plataforma, a linguagem em si muda pouco, o que muda é a filosofia geral dela que existe dois grandes grupos.

A linguagem em si muda pouco se a pessoa ou equipe dominá-la, e isso é mais importante. É um mito você escolher a linguagem certa para a tarefa. Claro que algumas são melhores que outras para certas tarefas, mas muda pouco na maioria dos casos, principalmente os casos mais comuns (exceto a questão de escolher uma linguagem de tipagem estática ou dinâmica, já dita antes).

Por via das dúvidas, se você acha que seu software vai escalar um dia, compensa escolher linguagens que escalam melhor tanto no sentido de performance quanto no sentido de [gerenciamento da base de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90297/101) ([detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364945/101)). Uma linguagem de tipagem estática, bem criada (não use linguagens mal criadas, PHP *cof cof*), com boa modularização, e que execute nativamente te dará melhores ferramentas para isto. Então se está preocupado com possível escala futura, mesmo que não precise agora, esqueça linguagens de *script* (algumas são menos de *script* que outras), as diferenças serão bem grandes, em alguns casos brutais.

Só reforço que na maioria dos casos você não terá essa escala toda que acha que terá, e se tiver provavelmente compensa trocar tudo depois, vimos isso ocorrer o tempo todo, e é algo bom, te dá a chance de arrumar muita coisa que agora você tem mais conhecimento sobre o problema.

Mas de forma geral você pensa em um dia trocar de linguagem se sua aplicação se mostrar ruim nela? Não, né?

Escolher um banco de dados adequado faz muito mais diferença que uma linguagem. Existem sim DBs que *performam* bem melhor em certas situações que outros, existem alguns que permitem modelos mais flexíveis e mais adequados para seu cenário. Entenda seu problema hoje e como ele poderá evoluir para fazer a escolha mais correta, este é o segredo. Escolher o PDO é admitir que você já está tomando a decisão errada, então reveja ela.

Mas se escolher errado de primeira faz pouca diferença na esmagadora maioria dos casos e nenhuma troca será necessária. E novamente, se for necessária só terá ganhos se mexer em tudo, não é o PDO que vai te salvar. E provavelmente terá ganho maior fazer certo no DB que já está usando. O PDO não salva um mal desenvolvedor tornando seu sistema ruim, a solução é ele arrumar o que fez de errado e nunca culpar a tecnologia comprovada.

Se optar por tecnologias obscuras pode acontecer dela ser culpada pelos seus problemas, improvável mas pode. Em tecnologia madura isso simplesmente não acontece, a não ser em altíssimas escalas, [o Uber já teve que trocar o DB](https://eng.uber.com/mysql-migration/), mesmo assim [mostraram que só porque eles estavam fazendo algo errado](https://thebuild.com/presentations/uber-perconalive-2017.pdf), mas na **sua** escala minúscula não importa.

Escolher certo é importante, mas se errar, a solução não é trocar o DB, e mesmo que seja, só se decidir reescrever todo acesso ao banco de dados, o PDO não te ajuda, só te ilude achando que ajuda.

Estou sendo repetitivo porque repetiram tantas vezes a mentira que trocar de DB é simples e fácil que é preciso deixar bem fixado que há problemas demais em fazer isso.

Só lembrando que trocar o MySQL pelo MariaDB (aconselho) não precisa trocar nada no código mesmo usando `mysqli`, nem trocar o modelo ou *queries*, o ganho não será grande, mas também não terá qualquer perda, só terá um software que evolui melhor e é "da comunidade".

## Segurança

Ao contrário do que a resposta aceita diz, a segurança do PDO não é melhor. O fato de criar uma abstração aumenta a chance do programador cometer algum erro sem perceber. Não tem nada nele que dê algum ponto a mais de segurança, é só uma afirmação sem base.

## Quando usar PDO?

Ficou claro que sempre deve usar `mysqli`, certo? Bom, sempre é um exagero, se você não liga pra performance, se quer ter um produto que precisa ser vendido marketeiramente com capacidade de trocar o banco de dados (do ponto de vista da engenharia isso não faz sentido) então pode ser uma boa.

Como a pergunta tem [php](/questions/tagged/php) eu vou dizer que esse argumento não costuma valer tanto a não ser pra um produto/plataforma como o Drupal citado em outra resposta, você está fazendo algo pra concorrer com o Drupal? Mesmo que esteja fazendo um CMS para seu uso ele não é uma plataforma. Note que o Wordpress não permite trocar o DB e ninguém deixa de usá-lo, e faz bem ser assim, ele seria bem pior se permitisse.

Pra falar bem a verdade eu nunca vi de verdade um site em PHP precisar trocar o DB, e nem vou repetir que se precisa vai ter um custo enorme que o PDO não vai te ajudar nada. A Wikipedia adotou o MySQL que é o que quase todo mundo adota em PHP e o usa até hoje (agora usa o MariaDB, mas o PDO não foi necessário), sendo uns dos 5 sites mais acessados do mundo (note que o modelo de documento poderia ser mais adequado pra ele - estou especulando).

Curiosamente tem linguagem que permite trocar de banco de dados de forma mais simples, sem o custo do PDO ou algo semelhante (mas ainda teria o problema que deveria ter que reescrever as *queries*).

## Mais mitos

#### O `mysqli` vai acabar

Já vi pessoas falando isso. Na verdade é a API chamada `mysql` que já acabou e não deve ser usada porque ela é ruim. A `mysqli` entrou no seu lugar, é oficial e não faz o menor sentido ela acabar, inclusive como você acha que o PDO acessa o MySQL?

#### Há recomendação de uso do PDO

As pessoas vivem repetindo isso, mas é uma recomendação dela ou de algum zé ninguém que ela leu, não há recomendação de nenhum órgão oficial, de um detentor de tecnologia (PHP por exemplo) ou mesmo de pessoas consideradas referência sobre o assunto, é o caso típico da mentira repetidas 1000 vezes que as pessoas passaram acreditar ser verdade. Há a recomendação que ele pode ser usado se ele for mais útil para você, o que é raro, e ele é melhor que usar a API `mysql`, mas não que seja recomendado em relação à `mysqli`.

#### O problema é o PDO

Na verdade o problema é a generalização, a abstração desnecessária, isso vale pra outras tecnologias que se comportam igual, mesmo em outras linguagens, e vale por exemplo pra maioria dos ORMs.

## Vantagens do `mysqli`

Nem todas vantagens foram mostradas nas outras respostas. Não sei se o PDO melhorou em alguma coisa, mas algumas coisas que vou colocar aqui talvez nem fossem vantagens da `mysqli` na época dessas respostas:

- Permite *queries* assíncronas, tão querida hoje em dia que pode dar uma percepção de *responsividade* muito melhor.
- Faz tudo o que o MySQL suporta, o PDO não permite usar todos recursos, muito do seu problema pode ser justamente por causa dessa limitação.
- As informações que a API te dá sobre o que acontece com as operações são muito mais ricas e pode te ajudar muito mais, não é possível em algo genérico.
- Não tem alguns potenciais *bugs* que o PDO tem, e que alguns não podem ser consertados porque virou semântica da API, ninguém fala nessas coisas (fechamento e limpeza automática por exemplo).
- Mais fácil fazer *queries* múltiplas.

## Conclusão

Use o `mysqli` a não ser que tenha certeza, que não seja só especulação, que o PDO vai te ajudar. Só use o PDO se tiver um domínio muito grande do que está fazendo, quando tiver "provas" que ele será útil, não embarque nessa de que as pessoas disseram que ele serve para alguma coisa, elas não estão preocupadas se isso é bom pra você, ou até mesmo para elas, só estão repetindo o que ouviram, não conhecem o assunto de fato.

Pra ser justo, se usar o PDO na maioria das vezes mudará muito pouco, não será tão ruim assim, mas será pior, e por que optar por algo claramente pior? A questão é que usará algo pior, mesmo que pouco, pra um ganho que não existe na prática.

As respostas aqui apontam a vantagem do PDO por puro formalismo, não é verdade na prática, em 99,9% do casos (número anedótico). Essa resposta era necessária porque em todo lugar as pessoas falam verdades e deixam o imaginário dos leitores completar com conclusões falsas (quase 100% das pessoas fazem isto porque elas nunca questionam o que estão lendo).

Não concorda? Ok, dê argumentos válidos, não falácias.

[image: Me convença do contrário meme]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: @Maneiro, a Wikipedia usa MariaDB (migração [começou em 2013](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2013/04/22/wikipedia-adopts-mariadb/)).. Não acho que altere em nada o contexto da resposta, só achei pertinente deixar como informação extra. :D

Comment: Ajuda mostrar que o MariaDB deveria sera preferência de todo mundo :D

Answer (score 17):

Vai depender do seu projeto, a diferença do PDO não é lá tão grande como pararece, 
como exemplo, o [Drupal](https://drupal.org/) que é um senhor CMS usa PDO, e como exmplo o eclipse usa o drupal no seu [market place](http://marketplace.eclipse.org).

Minha recomendação: Use o PDO.  A não ser que sua aplicação dependa vitalmente da velocidade, nesse caso use o MySQLi

Answer (score 17):

A grande vantagem do `PDO` comparado ao `mysqli` é que ele possui suporte a vários bancos de dados e permite o uso de nomes parametrizados nas consultas preparadas enquanto o `mysqli` suporta apenas o *MySQL* e nas consulta `preparads` usa-se apenas `?` . No manual existe uma comparações das funcionalidades PDO, mysqli e mysql nesse [link](https://www.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing).

Segue outros links que fazem a comparação:

[PDO vs Mysqli which should you use net](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

[With is better Mysqli or PDO in PHP](http://www.letitlearn.com/2013/09/which-is-better-mysqli-or-pdo-in-php/)