# Como lidar com multiplas queries?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho uma dúvida relacionada a boas práticas de programação. Como lidar com várias queries em uma mesma página em PHP. Por exemplo, o código:

```
    $qr = "SELECT historico.*, funcionarios.nome FROM historico INNER JOIN funcionarios ON (historico.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id)";
    $resultado = mysql_query($qr);
```

Logo mais abaixo na minha página, tenho que fazer uma outra query:

```
    $qr2 = "SELECT diasplantao.*, funcionarios.nome FROM diasplantao INNER JOIN funcionarios ON (diasplantao.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id)";      
    $resultado2 = mysql_query($qr2);
```

E assim por diante, podendo existir até outras ainda. Minha dúvida é: Qual a melhor maneira de gerenciar isso? Há alguma maneira de fazer com que o código não fique tão bagunçado, com tantas variáveis.

Comment: Se forem seguidas podes usar o método [multi-query](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php). Já agora aconselho a usar [mysqli](http://pt1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) uma vez que mysql será descontinuada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um maneira de melhorar a organização de um projeto procedural é separar o php do html e quebrar o código(macarrão) em funções. Lembre também de utilizar api's modernas para conexão com banco de dados evitando as funções mysql_*

**Exemplo:**

macarrao.php

```
<?php
    $qr = "SELECT historico.*, funcionarios.nome FROM historico 
           INNER JOIN funcionarios
           ON (historico.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id)";
    $resultado = mysql_query($qr);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Matricula</td>
        <td>Data entrada</td>
        <td>Data saida</td>
    </tr>

    <?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo
    '<tr>
        <td>'. $row['nome']  .'</td>
        <td>'. $row['matricula'] .'</td>
        <td>'. $row['entrada'] .'</td>
        <td>'. $row['saida'] .'</td>
    </tr>';
    ?>

</table>
```

1 - Remova o código do inicio e o while do macarrao.php e crie um novo arquivo que pode ser  sql/funcionarios.php, ficará dessa forma:

```
include 'conexao.php';

function getHistorio($conexao){
    $sql = 'SELECT historico.*, funcionarios.nome FROM historico
            INNER JOIN funcionarios
            ON (historico.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id)';
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());

   $historicos = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
       $historicos[] = $row;
   }
    return $historicos;
}
//outras funções....
```

2 - Copie o conteudo html do macarrão.php para um arquivo novo, view/lista_historico.php que terá apenas um foreach para listar os historicos

```
<?php
    include 'sql/funcionario.php';
    $historico = getHistorio($conexao);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Matricula</td>
        <td>Data entrada</td>
        <td>Data saida</td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreah($historico as $item){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item['nome']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['matricula']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['entrada']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['saida']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Flat PHP vs Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html)

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

Comment: Isso é boa pratica ou mesmo só questão de gosto?

Comment: @JorgeB, Blocos monoliticos de código são sucetíveis a problemas de escopo, variáveis perdidas etc quebrar isso em funções menores separa as responsabilidades e torna o código reutilizável.

Comment: Eu digo isto que eu tenho algum código que era práticamente impossivel de por assim, fica bem mais compreensivel da forma em 1.

Answer (score 5):

Eu particularmente prefiro utilizar nomes completos que facilitam o debug posterior e manutenção por outras pessoas. Exemplo:

```
$queryFuncionarios 

$queryDiasPlantao
```

Assim facilita muito

Comment: Como o Otto falou a cima, sempre procuro associar a query com o nome da tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de executar múltiplas queries você precisa analisar se são queries independentes ou não.

Imagine, por exemplo, um sistema de log de ações que registre todas as ações feitas por um determinado usuário.

Se você executar duas queries ao mesmo tempo, uma para inserir e outra para registrar a inclusão pelo usuário X, se a primeira falhar e a segunda não, você passa a ter inconsistência de informações.

Claro, num sistema de logs que normalmente é frequentemente limpo não chega a ser um problema preocupante, mas é um problema de fato.

Ao passo que se você tentar inserir e falhar, a segunda query não será executada e, de quebra, você ainda poderia manipular o erro informando ao usuáiro que aquela ação em específico falhou, ao invés de um erro geral de "alguma coisa deu errado".