# Criação de tabelas com scripts de Base de Dados

Tags: php, mysql

Na minha aplicação tenho de criar uma tabela para cada utilizador, as tabelas são criadas a primeira vez quando o utilizador faz o upload de um ficheiro e com o nome tabela_$id_user. E a única forma que vejo para criar assim dinamicamente é esta:

```
$sql_create_table1 =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`table1` (
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
                ...
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;";

$mysqli->query( $sql_create_table1 );
...
```

Tenho visto muita coisa ao longo dos anos e optei por fazer assim, sem ter muita noção se estaria a fazer da forma correta.

**É correto fazer isto desta forma?**

**Que problemas podem surgir ao criar assim tabelas?**

**Existe outra forma de fazer isto?**

Fiquei com muitas dúvidas sobre a forma de programar em PHP ao ler [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16398/7210).

Comment: Não quero entrar na base da opinião, mas sim na base de que o código assim é suscetível a problemas?

Comment: Me parece que se trata de um *Code Review* então. Não lembro como tá o status disso lá no [meta]... E me parece também que são 4 perguntas embutidas numa só, deixando a pergunta *Ampla Demais*... mas vou me abster de votar... muitas dúvidas ;)

Comment: Acho que para responder isso eu preciso perguntar: que vantagens *você* vê no método que usa hoje? Porque à primeira vista me parece mais simples eliminar o PHP e simplesmente executar o SQL, seja no Workbench, ou outra ferramenta. Eu pessoalmente uso a linha de comando pra isso: `mysql --user=root --password=blabla nome_da_base < arquivo.sql`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Que tipo de problemas podem surgir com este método que eu uso?

Um problema óbvio que me ocorre é ter de escapar todas as aspas duplas (`"`) que houver dentro dos seus SQL *statements* (por exemplo, em uma string sendo inserida numa tabela que você acabou de criar).

> Existe algum standard para isso?

Não exatamente, mas você está empacotando SQL como strings PHP, quando poderia simplesmente escrever SQL puro, e executar em um client qualquer (Workbench, linha de comando ou outro).

> Seria melhor prática fazer de outra forma?

Isso eu não sei e me parece opinativo. O termo "melhor prática" por si só já me desagrada. Se é para dar opinião, eu simplesmente usaria SQL puro, sem PHP, pela simplicidade.

---

Considerando a última edição da pergunta: eu fugiria dessa estrutura de uma tabela por usuário, e usaria uma única tabela com uma coluna `usuario_id`.

Comment: Estou encarando esta pergunta como "faço isto assim; de que outras maneiras posso fazer, e como se comparam à que uso atualmente?" Isso pode ser respondido sem opiniões, apesar de a pergunta ter um lado que pode levar as pessoas a opinarem (por exemplo, falar em "forma correta" e "melhor prática").

Comment: Editei a pergunta, se quiser mudar a resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Adicionei uma observação no final.

Answer (score 1):

Não é uma boa prática isso que tu estás fazendo de criar uma tabela para cada usuário! O certo seria tu criam uma única tabela com uma chave estrangeira apontando para a tabela de usuário.

Porém se tu insistir nesse modo de fazer, creio que não há jeito melhor do que o jeito que tu fez mesmo.

Comment: Estás a dar a resposta baseada na tua opinião e não factos. Workbench porque? Não respondeste a pergunta.

Comment: Estás me a dizer as vantagens de utilizar essa ferramenta. Não é isso que quero saber até porque já sei. O que eu quero saber é porque não usar da forma que eu uso, existe alguma forma mais adequada? Lê [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16370/7210) e a resposta, é mais ou menos isso que eu quero saber.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, se quiser mudar a resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. O maior problema dessa pergunta, na minha humilde opinião, não é que ela é baseada em opiniões, mas é que não está claro o que tu realmente quer. Acho que eu nem devia ter respondido, na verdade. =)