# Boas práticas com grandes queries?

Tags: php, sql, query

Existem boas práticas quando se trata de queries SQL dentro do php?
Ou existe alguma alternativa pra não "sujar" o código com uma query gigante no meio?
Edit: O que eu estava procurando era justamente views, só que eu não sabia o nome pelo que procurar, a resposta escolhida sana todas as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Olá Vinícius, tudo bem? Só pra tu conseguir entender bem os Downvotes: evita perguntas de caráter opinativo e pessoal, sempre traz códigos (ou parte de código) para melhor ilustrar e exemplificar a pergunta e sempre pesquisa, aqui menos por aqui mesmo, se já não existe a tua pergunta e resposta pra ela.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer com query gigante é uma query com mais de 10 linhas por exemplo no meio do código php.
Eu estava vendo que bons métodos são métodos com poucas linhas e com divisão de responsabilidades. Não sei se existe alguma forma de melhorar o código quando se trata disso. Eu tentei pesquisar sobre isso antes mas não encontrei nada falando sobre, ou talvez procurei pela coisa errada.

Comment: Considerar o uso de uma ORM pode resolver seu problema

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como lidar com multiplas queries?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16370/como-lidar-com-multiplas-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente criar uma view no banco de dados e chamar no código PHP. Dessa forma você evita ter que chamar uma longa query e deixa a lógica toda na view. Pelo que eu pesquisei aqui é possível.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/pawarnitesh/home/php/mysql_view_php Neste link há um exemplo para você ver. Não sei se você já usou view antes.