# Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "Select * from servico where ID_SERVICO = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $nome = $row['NOME'];       

    if($nome == 'Marketing') {
        include ("servicos/marketing.php"); 
    }
    if($nome == 'Web-Marketing') {              
        include ('servicos/webmarketing.php');
    }
    if($nome == 'Serviços Web') {
        include ("servicos/servicosweb.php");
    }
    if($nome == 'Design Gráfico') {
        include ("servicos/designgrafico.php");
    }
}
```

Eu tenho este código e não consigo ver erro nisto, mas ele dá-me este erro. Eu sei que já deve existir um tópico deste no site mas já tentei todas as maneiras e nada. Dá me o erro bool(false)

Comment: Esse acontece quando sua consulta falha, vc pode imprimir ela e testar direto no banco ou fazer o mysq_* mostrar o erro do banco assim: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado.

Comment: Qual era o problema?

Comment: Era um nome errado na query, falta de atenção minha.

Answer (score 15):

Esse erro acontece quando `mysql_query()` ou `mysqli_query()` falha, normalmente é um erro de sintaxe na consulta sql e retorna um `false` como explicado no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php). Para [mysql_fetch_*()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) funcionar corretamente é necessario passar uma variável do tipo `resource` ou `mysqli_resource` que é o retorno de `mysql_query()`/`mysqli_query()` em caso de sucesso.

Para corrigir o erro você pode forçar o mysql_* */mysqli_* * a exibir o erro do banco com a função [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php) ou [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Versão com as funções antiga mysql_*

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM desc';
$resource = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Versão com o mysqli_* procedural

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM desc';
$resource = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Versão com mysqli_* OO

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM desc';
$resource = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error);
```

A consulta vai retornar esse erro porque `desc` é uma palavra reservado do mysql.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'desc'

A outra forma é imprimir a consulta e testar diretamente no banco:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM desc';
echo $sql;
```

Relacionado:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar)

[Como printar a instrução SQL que está sendo enviada ao banco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34811/91)

Comment: Eu botei a recompensa pra pergunta e a sua resposta ganharem mais votos e mais relevância, servindo como canônicas pra várias duplicatas. Mas parece que não deu muito certo.

Comment: @bfavaretto valeu a intenção :)

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre porque o método `mysql_query` necessita de um parâmetro com a conexão com o banco de dados.

Deixo abaixo um exemplo. Lembre-se de modificar os dados para conexão com o banco.

Deixo como dica para você estudar o uso do [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) pois ele é mais seguro e o `mysql_*` já está depreciado..

> Exemplo:

```
$query = "Select * from servico where ID_SERVICO = $id";
// variavel com a conexão do banco de dados.
$conn = mysql_connect('servidor', 'usuario', 'senha') or die ('Verifique seus dados de conexão com o banco de dados. Detalhes: ' . mysql_error());
// selecionando banco de dados
mysql_select_db('nome_do_banco', $conn);

$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $nome = $row['NOME'];       

    if($nome == 'Marketing') {
        include ("servicos/marketing.php"); 
    }
    if($nome == 'Web-Marketing') {              
        include ('servicos/webmarketing.php');
    }
    if($nome == 'Serviços Web') {
        include ("servicos/servicosweb.php");
    }
    if($nome == 'Design Gráfico') {
        include ("servicos/designgrafico.php");
    }
}
```