# Erro "Undefined variable"

Tags: php, query, variáveis

Estou tentando correr este código mas não está funcionando.

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id = $id ";
$limite = mysql_query("$sql");

while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite)){

    $nome       = $sql["nome"];
    $telefone   = $sql["telefone"];

    $id         = $_GET['id'];

    echo "<div class='clientecelula'>" ;
    echo "$nome"; 
    echo "<span class='telcelula'> $telefone </span>";
    echo "<span class='semcelula'>  </span>";
    echo "</div>" ; 

}
```

Estou obtendo o erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ross/semana.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ross/semana.php
>   on line 12

Qual o problema aqui?

Comment: Julgo esse tipo de pergunta fora de escopo pois está mais para pedido de ajuda/suporte para resolver algo pessoal. 
Acho que não cabe a comunidade ficar fazendo o serviço de terceiros..

Comment: @DanielOmine pedidos de ajuda em bugs no código são dentro do escopo.

Comment: acho que a pergunta está dentro do escopo, acho que vocês confundem as coisas, não é por que alguém está perdido com algo básico que ela é fora do escopo

Comment: `$_GET['id']` veio vazio e causou um erro na sql que retornou um false. [pergunta com erro relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28190/91)

Comment: @rray o problema não é esse, o problema é a localização da atribuição do `$id`.

Comment: Discordo. Para mim, isso é fora de escopo. Não acho que esse tipo de questão agrege valor comunitário. Isso é como fazer o serviço de outros, de graça.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Gostaria de pedir desculpas por fazer uma pergunta tão básica e que muito falaram que estava fora de escopo. Eu ainda sou um estudante e estou o php só a 2 meses.

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema está na variável `$id` que é atribuída depois de já a estar a ser usada no SQL.

Se trocares de sítio já resolves **esse** problema:

```
$id     = $_GET['id'];
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id = $id ";
$limite = mysql_query($sql);

while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite))
{
    $nome       = $sql["nome"];
    $telefone   = $sql["telefone"];

    echo "<div class='clientecelula'>" ;
    echo "$nome"; 
    echo "<span class='telcelula'> $telefone </span>";
    echo "<span class='semcelula'>  </span>";
    echo "</div>" ; 

}
```

**IMPORTANTE:** Aconselho o uso de funções do tipo [`mysqli_`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) porque as funções do tipo [`mysql_`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.mysql.php) será descontinuada como poderá ver [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined variable

diz que a variável não existe e no código exibido na pergunta `$id` está definida depois que a consulta foi executa
e você precisa dela ante disso, como ela será usada como um argumento na SQL não deixe de verificar se o seu valor é valido, force um *cast* para inteiro.

Prefira `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysqsl_error())` no lugar de `mysql_query($sql);` a primeira forma ira exibir a mensagem de erro do banco de dados caso a consulta
falhe que pode ser desde um erro de sintaxe até algum outro problema mais grave.

```
>>#a última linha do while deveria estar aqui<<

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id = $id ";
$limite = mysql_query("$sql");

while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite)){
    $nome       = $sql["nome"];
    $telefone   = $sql["telefone"];
    $id         = $_GET['id'];    <----- essa linha deveria estar antes da atribuição de $sql
}
```

O código corrigido fica assim:

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id = $id ";
$limite = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite)){
    $nome       = $sql["nome"];
    $telefone   = $sql["telefone"];
    $id         = $sql['id'];
}
```

Caso o código seja de um projeto novo é altamente recomendado utilizar o mysqli ou PDO.
Leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

Comment: Tchi já tinha a resposta pronta, vou responder na mesma

Comment: Já agora o `while` não fecha ali...

Comment: @JorgeB. vc diz para remover essa linha `$id = $sql['id'];` ou colocar os echos ?

Comment: Colocar os echos...

Comment: E essa linha também não consta do código do AP