# Erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql

Bom estou tentando fazer um "Sistema de Cadastro com PHP e MySQL" fiz isso seguindo todas as instruções me passadas mas na hora do resultado ele retorna a seguinte mensagem.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Formulario\cadastrado.php on line 25

Abaixo vai meu código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Formulário de inscrição</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $host = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pass = "";
            $banco = "cadastro";
            $conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($banco)or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
        <?php
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
            $dataNasc = $_POST['dataNasc'];
            $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
            $comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];
            $sql mysql_query("INSERT INTO funcionarios(nome, sobrenome, nascimento, telefone, email, bairro, comentarios)VALUES('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$dataNasc', '$telefone', '$email', '$bairro', '$comentarios')");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

E agora um print que eu acho que pode ajudar...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então poderiam me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

Comment: Seja bem vindo. Não use o StackSnippets para códigos PHP. PHP não funciona nele, as caixas estão marcadas com css/js/html então poste apenas isto dentro deles. Para duvidas com código que não podem ser reproduzidos via navegador use o icone que se parece com isto `{ }`. Não use titulo, *Iniciante*, *Ajuda*, *Help*, *Por favor*. Use titulos intuitivos e que tem haver com o problema, siga o exemplo das demais perguntas que você pode ver na página inicial.

Comment: Aproveite e veja o [wiki do php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) lá tem algumas boas dicas e materiais para começar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING)

Erro de sintaxe ele diz mais ou menos 'algo está fora lugar/ordem certo', aqui é necessário fazer uma atribuição use o sinal de igual(`=`) para isso.

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) retorna um resource em caso de sucesso do contrário retorna um false que significa que a sua consulta falhou, por isso é importante usar o [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) para saber se a consulta tem um erro ou se ele foi gerado devido a violação de restrição do banco.

```
$sql mysql_query("....
```

Mude para:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
```

Como é iniciante ainda, recomendo não usar as funções mysql_* elas estão obsoletas.

Leitura obrigatória:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Erro comum - mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28184/91)

Comment: Nossa... Mudei isso e o erro passou pra linha 14.. E eu me lembro de ter visto em algum lugar que deveria ser adicionado o @ antes de mysql_connect e consegui tirar o erro.. Muito obrigado, rray

Comment: Não use `@` ele omite o erro, o certo é tratar eles. @naldson

Comment: "o certo é tratar eles." como?

Comment: Se o projeto for legado(antigo) faça questão de sempre ver o erro gerado pelo banco, nesse caso vc precisa usar o `mysql_error()`. Assim:
`mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` @Naldson

Answer (score 3):

Você não atribuiu a variável `$sql`, esqueceu do `=`, pra deixar funcionando corretamente utilize `$sql = mysql_query(`, não use `@` antes, isso irá omitir os erros, você tem que trata-los corretamente pra não ficar com um código "sujo".

Mas antes de mais nada, não recomendo mais o uso do `mysql_query*` ela se tornou [obsoleta,](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration53.deprecated.php)

Já que és iniciante, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

mas ao evoluir, eu recomendo fortemente o `PDO`, pois é mais seguro e orientado a objetos.