# Erro Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() e nenhum erro retornado em mysqli_error

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com um erro simples e não consigo encontrar uma solução, me parece que meu problema é diferente desta [resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in).

A mensagem de erro é esta: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in **** on line 22`

Arquivo conexao.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sis");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Erro de conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

Arquivo principal onde o erro acontece:

```
include_once('conexao.php');

$senha = '123456';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM arquivo WHERE senha = '$senha'";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1){

    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    echo $dados['idarquivo'];
}
```

Em meu banco de dados com nome `sis` na tabela `arquivo` eu tenho uma linha em que a coluna `senha` tem o valor `123456`.

A linha 22 corresponde a `$dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);`

Comment: Tem dois `mysqli_fetch_*()` basta um ou outro, o segundo não deveria existir. Ele está recebendo um array (`$resultado`) quando talvez deveria receber um resource (`$query`). Depois é só mudar para `echo $resultado['idarquivo'];`

Comment: @rray obrigado pela resposta, se possível coloque sua resposta para que eu coloque a minha dúvida como respondida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe dois instruções `mysqli_fetch_*()` a segunda recebe um array quando não deveria existir ou deveria receber um resource.

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1){
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); //instrução errada
```

Para resolver basta remover ela e trocar o nome da variável no echo de `$dados` para `$resultado`.