# Exibição de dados em menu dinamico em PHP sem resultados

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, menu

Olá.

Estou desde o principio da semana a tentar acabar o menu dinamico que criei mas não consigo exibir o div correspondente ao link bem como o respectivo conteudo.

Descrevendo melhor, tenho um subMenu com os continentes e cada um deles deverá abrir um div com outro submenu contendo os respectivos países. Até aqui consigo exibir os resultados no submenu dos continentes mas depois não consigo abrir os divs dos países.

Com o cansaço e a motivação a descerem, pergunto-vos qual o caminho a seguir, pois já experimentei várias soluções e não consigo resolver o problema.

Abaixo tenho o codigo em PHP, mod_menu.php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<div id="container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>                 
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="destinations">destinations</a>
<div id="subMenu">                   
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "site_comboios";

    //Abre ligação à BD
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Error connecting to database';
    exit();
         }

//show sub-menu
$query = "SELECT * FROM continentes ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);     
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $Cont = $row['continente'];
echo "<div class='nav-column'><a href='#cnt_submenu' data-id='<?php   $query ?>' class='continente'>" .($Cont). "</a></div> ";    
        }
 ?>                      

 </div>                    
    </li>                
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>         
 </div> 

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente  active">    
<?php
//retrieve european countries from DB and open <ul> with 9 results
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","site_comboios");
$sql_eurCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE   id_continentes = 1";
$result_eurCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_eurCountries);

if($result_eurCountries > 0) { 
    while ($row_eurCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_eurCountries))   {
    $país_Eur = $row_eurCountries['id_continentes'];
    echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $país_Eur ."</a>";
}

} else if ($result_eurCountries == 9) {
       echo '</li></ul>';
       }
?>
<span class="close">x</span>
</div>

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente active">
<?php
//retrieve african countries from DB  
$sql_afrCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE   id_continentes = 2";
$result_afrCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_afrCountries);

while ($row_afrCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_afrCountries)) {
     $pais_Afr = $row_afrCountries['id_continentes'];
     echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $pais_Afr ."</a></li></ul>";
      }
 ?>
 </div>

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente active">
<?php
//retrieve asian countries from DB 
$sql_asiaCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE  id_continentes = 3";
$result_asiaCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_asiaCountries);

if($sql_asiaCountries == FALSE) {
      die(mysqli_errno($conn));
      }

while ($row_asiaCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_asiaCountries)) {
      $pais_Asia = $row_asiaCountries['id_continentes'];
      echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $pais_Asia ."</a></li></ul>";
      }

?>
</div>

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente active">
<?php
//retrieve oceania countries from DB 
$sql_oceaCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE id_continentes = 4";
$result_oceaCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_oceaCountries);

if($sql_oceaCountries == FALSE) {
       die(mysqli_errno($conn));
      }

while ($row_oceaCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_oceaCountries)) {
    $pais_Oceania = $row_oceaCountries['id_continentes'];
    echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $pais_Oceania ."</a></li></ul>";
      }
?>
</div>

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente  active">
<?php
//retrieve north america countries from DB 
$sql_norCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE  id_continentes = 5";
$result_norCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_norCountries);

if($sql_norCountries == FALSE) {
    die(mysqli_errno($conn));
    }

while ($row_norCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_norCountries)) {
$pais_North = $row_norCountries['id_continentes'];
echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $pais_North ."</a></li></ul>";
}
?>
</div>

<div id="cnt_submenu" data-id="divSub" class="submenu_continente  active">
<?php
//retrieve south america countries from DB 
$sql_sulCountries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE  id_continentes = 6";
$result_sulCountries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_sulCountries);

if($sql_sulCountries == FALSE) {
      die(mysqli_errno($conn));
     }

while ($row_sulCountries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sulCountries)) {
      $pais_South = $row_sulCountries['id_continentes'];
      echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $pais_South ."</a></li></ul>";
}
?>
</div>
```

E o codigo jQuery que exibe o respectivo div conforme  cada continente:

```
$('.continente').hover(function(){
    var subCountry = $(this).data('id');
    $('divSub').show(subCountry);
        });
```

Para além de não aparecer nenhum div, no PHP tenho o seguinte erro:

"mysqli_fetch_assoc expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean given in"

Em relação a este erro, tentei criar uma ligação à BD em cada subDiv, mas o erro persistia.

Agradeço a vossa ajuda.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187430/3635

Comment: Experimente trocar `SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE   id_continentes = 1` por `SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id_continentes = 1 ORDER BY id`.