# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean ao consultar function ajudinha

Tags: php, mysqli

estou fazendo uma função que quando recebe um numero , no caso, um id ele faz uma consulta e resgata o nome que esta nesse id e me deparo com esse erro.

código

```
function catporid($cat){

    global $aCon;

    $sql = 'SELECT cat_nome FROM cat WHERE cat_id = $cat';  

    $query = $aCon->query($sql);   

    $r = $query->fetch_array();    

    $cat = $r['cat_nome'];  

    return $cat."id";

}
```

Comment: Aplique correcção na variável `$cat` usando aspas, por causa disso o que obtens é um bool em vez do objecto pretendido.

Comment: corrigi só que o erro ainda continua $sql = "SELECT cat_nome FROM cat WHERE cat_id = '$cat'";

Comment: Vê na resposta, apresentei duas formas como podes corrigir isso.

Comment: Relacionada, se não duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in

Comment: @Edilson resolvido ! era uma coluna com nome diferente e mudei um pouco o código .. obrigado !

Comment: Mesmo já tendo sido escolhida uma resposta, gostaria de acrescentar uma dica importante. Sempre que acontence um erro desses é por que há erro de sintaxe na consulta sql. Em vez de adivinhar onde está o erro basta usar a variavel de conexão com o banco para retornar o ultimo erro ocorrido. Mais ou menos assim: echo $conexao->error;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chavetas `{` para trabalhar com variáveis dentro de aspas:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_nome FROM cat WHERE cat_id = '{$cat}'";
```

Ou podes também fazer isto:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_nome FROM cat WHERE cat_id = '". $cat . "'";
```

É também recomendando que verifiques se foram retornados resultados dessa consulta, antes de tentares imprimir ou capturar qualquer valor.

```
function catporid($cat){
    global $aCon;
    $stmt = "SELECT cat_nome FROM cat WHERE cat_id = '{$cat}'";

    if($query = $aCon->query($stmt)){
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            $r = $query->fetch_array();
            return $r['id'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: fiz a modificação, nao acusa erros porem nao da resultado. precisa de mais informações ?

Comment: @Drbs ainda está com erros ?

Answer (score 0):

### De acordo com a documentação php , MySQLi :: query ():

> Retorna FALSE em caso de falha. Para consultas SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE
>   ou EXPLAIN bem-sucedidas mysqli_query () retornará um objeto
>   mysqli_result. Para outras consultas bem-sucedidas mysqli_query ()
>   retornará TRUE. Isso significa que a consulta a seguir está falhando

```
 $mysqli->query($bup);
```

> O que significa que alguma instrução no sql em uma variável está causando um erro. Eu recomendo revisão ou teste de mesa. Parece que o erro não é um erro de
>   sintaxe (uma vez que um erro de sintaxe teria causado uma mensagem de
>   erro ainda mais complexa), o que significa que o MySQL pode ler sua
>   declaração, mas a operação está falhando por algum motivo. Você terá
>   que rever sua instrução SQL, bem como sua tabela e ver o que a falha
>   na lógica é.

Fonte: [Fonte 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455186/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-array-on-boolean)