# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer given

Tags: php, mysqli

Possuo esse código abaixo:

```
<?php
$conecta_no_banco = require_once ('conecta_db.php');
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conecta_no_banco,"SELECT usuario FROM gerenciador_de_socios.autenticacao_usuarios") or die("Erro!");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if(!$login || !$senha) {
    echo "Você deve digitar sua senha e login!";
    exit;
}

if ($row > 0) {
    echo "OK!";
}
mysqli_close($conecta_no_banco);
?>
```

Quando executo, dá o erro:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer
>   given

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Esta é uma das perguntas mais frequentes sobre PHP e o próprio erro diz o motivo.... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=expects%20parameter%20given%20%5bphp%5d, o problema ainda está na linha que dependente do `$conecta_no_banco`, que esta omitido no código, ele é o problemático.

Comment: @Inkeliz nesse caso teria que ver o que possui em conecta_db.php.
Em conecta_db.php, para que seu código funcione, deve possui algo no final como `return $variavel_de_conexao`

Comment: Agora que notei isso, possivelmente deve ser ai o problema, mas não há como saber.

Comment: Nunca fiz algo do tipo, quando dou um require_once, costumo usar as funções e variáveis criadas no arquivo "filho" (que vem do require_once) no arquivo "pai", se o return for omitido o valor que retorna é um integer (1) se o arquivo existir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste código que você tem, remova a linha:

```
$conecta_no_banco = require_once ('conecta_db.php');
```

e altere para

```
require_once ('conecta_db.php');
```

e dentro do arquivo **conecta_db.php** altere seu código de conexão para algo parecido com isto:

```
$conecta_no_banco = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Muito Muito Obrigado!