# GROUP BY e ORDER BY MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Quando envio a Query:

`SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' ORDER BY ano DESC`

É retornado valores duplicados, porquê existem valores duplicados na tabela. Más quero retornar apenas uma vez cada ano contido na tabela.

Más sem sucesso ao enviar as query's abaixo:

`SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' GROUP BY ano ORDER BY ano DESC`

`SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' ORDER BY ano DESC GROUP BY ano`

```
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [...]
```

Imagem do banco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura da tabela: [aqui](http://pagebin.com/DvzDdHP9)

Comment: Usa distinct... SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' ORDER BY ano DESC

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo continuou a mesma coisa, irei editar a pergunta e com o anexo do banco de dados!

Comment: Pelo erro que esta dando o erro não esta na sua `query`, a sua primeira `query` esta correta. Tente executa-la no `PHPMyAdmin` diretamente. Coloque também todo o seu código `php` para analisarmos.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes mesmo no PHPMyAdmin continuou trazendo os resultados com o ano duplicado

Comment: Tira um print da `query ` que esta executando e do resultado no PHPMyAdmin

Comment: http://imgur.com/zCdTuhC

Comment: Pergunta, você quer trazer só um registro do usuário? Ou quer trazer todos os anos do usuário sem repetir?

Comment: todos os anos do usuário sem repetir

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in

Comment: SELECT id, id_cliente, mes, status,ano FROM programacao_cliente_mes WHERE id_cliente = 2 GROUP BY mes, ano ORDER BY ano DESC

Answer (score 1):

Para trazer todos os anos do usuário sem repetir, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ano, id, id_cliente, mes, status
FROM programacao_clientes_mes
WHERE id_cliente = 2
ORDER BY ano DESC
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/bUEpVrp

Comment: Tenta colocar parenteses depois do DISTINCT conforme alterei na resposta

Comment: sem êxito Roberto, http://imgur.com/8lDMsYB

Comment: Você sabe qual a versão do seu MySql ?

Comment: Versão do servidor: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Fiz uma nova alteração, coloquei o `DISTINCT ano` como primeiro campo, vê se funciona agora

Comment: Roberto, ainda com dados duplicados http://imgur.com/yxTkiLG

Comment: Executa essa `query`: `SELECT DISTINCT(ano) ano, id, id_cliente, mes, status, LENGTH(ano)
FROM programacao_clientes_mes
WHERE id_cliente = 2
ORDER BY ano DESC` e me mostra o resultado

Comment: http://imgur.com/Fp56eT5

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62021/discussion-between-roberto-fagundes-and-mustache-web).

Comment: Me mostra o resultado dessa `query`: `SELECT id, id_cliente, mes, STATUS, ano
FROM programacao_clientes_mes
WHERE id_cliente = 2
GROUP BY ano
ORDER BY ano DESC`

Comment: Vou lhe mandar no chat!

Comment: Vou aguardar la

Comment: http://imgur.com/euJeo8Z

Comment: Execute este comando `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` no PHPMyAdmin e depois execute novamente o `select` anterior e poste aqui o resultado.

Comment: Roberto, por um momento foi funcional, más ao adicionar outro registro voltou a "duplicar"

Comment: Mostre o resultado

Comment: http://imgur.com/wQdDP5V

Comment: Provavelmente todas as vezes que você fizer a conexão com o banco de dados, será necessário executar esta `query`: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Answer (score 0):

Se fizer desse forma agrupando pelo ID e ano deve vir o resultado esperado

```
SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' GROUP BY ano,id_cliente ORDER BY ano,id_cliente DESC
```

Comment: infelizmente não foi. continuo um aviso de Query!

Comment: Tenta: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' GROUP BY ano ORDER BY ano ASC

Comment: O que você tem no $id_cliente? Posta o código por inteiro, fica melhor de avaliar.

Comment: André em $id_cliente tenho uma string = "2" ! o código é parte de uma função de uma classe, irei posta-lo

Answer (score 0):

A order da query é primeiro `GROUP BY` e depois `ORDER BY`

Ai ficaria `SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' GROUP BY ano ORDER BY ano DESC`

Comment: como citado na pergunta, essa query me retorna um aviso!

**#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'GROUP BY ano LIMIT 0, 25' na linha 1**

Comment: Colocar o codigo completo que está fazendoa  chamada. o problema está dando no mysqli parece ser formaçao de query, mas se não for pode ser outra coisa, que não da pra ver sem o codigo.

e manda o erro completo também, está com `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguintee forma:

```
SELECT id, id_cliente, mes, status, ano FROM programacao_clientes_mes WHERE id_cliente = 2 GROUP BY mes, ano ORDER BY ano DESC
```

Comment: André, sem Êxito. http://imgur.com/Y1x5qSb

Comment: Cara, posta a estrutura da sua tabela... exporta ela e posta a estrutura dela, do CREATE TABLE

Comment: http://pagebin.com/DvzDdHP9

Comment: Deleta o campo id e coloca ele id, int, 10, auto_increment, primary, pra ver... o erro acho que está ai!

Comment: O erro ainda persiste!