# Problema mysqli_fetch_assoc() | não é nada a ver com bolean ;)

Tags: mysqli

sou novo aqui, estou com um problema no codigo abaixo.: alguem consegue me dar uma luz?

**Codigo.:**

```
<tbody> 
   <?php
   while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado))
   {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['ID'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['id'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['id'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['id'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['id'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $linha['id'] .'</td>';
      echo '</tr>'; 
   }    
   mysqli_close ($conexao);     
   ?>
</tbody>
```

**Erro.:**

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   /home/u666149583/public_html/bootstrap/motorista/listar.php on line 70

Comment: Tem um ID maiúsculo ali.

Comment: Se não é nada a ver, vc tem a disposição o link "editar" para explicar na sua pergunta qual o problema.

Comment: A mensagem `mysqli_result, null given`, significa que a variável `$resultado` passada em `mysqli_fetch_assoc` esta com o valor `NULL`. Ou seja é o mesmo problema que o @ÐvÐ citou sim, pois mysqli_fetch_assoc espera um valor especifico, sendo null ou boolean é independente, a situação é que você não checou o valor de `$resultado` e a resposta linkada explica como fazer. Outra resposta didática seria esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28190/3635

Comment: ok, eu sou iniciante ainda, poderia me falar como resolvo ? eu não entendi :/

Comment: A resposta do rray não é didática https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28190/3635? Achei que ele explicou tão bem, tenta dar uma lida novamente se possível.