# Site somente funciona local, nao funciona online

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma simples conexão que minha aplicação usa para conectar no banco `mysql`.

Localmente estava tudo bem, porem ao colocar online não funciona mais. Já mudei vários termos possíveis para o erro que vi aqui no tópico e não deu certo. A conexão com o banco esta correta, porém a verificação de login não vai.

Segue meu código:

**Conexao.php**

[image: Código de conexão com o banco de dados]

**Login.php**

[image: Função para verificação de login e senha]

**Erro**

> conexao_ok Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   /customers/0/f/7/theydo.com.br/httpd.www/bd/Logar.php on line 9
>   Login_erro

OBS: Já tentei `mysql_num_rows`, mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo, favor [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/270708/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código em vez de **imagem**! Aproveite e faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)

Comment: Tenta `if($sql && mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)`

Comment: Os dados de conexão estão corretos? Adicione um `or die($dbcon->error);` depois do `select`. Verifique se `$dbcon->query` está retornando `false` pois `mysqli_num_rows` só aceita `mysqli_result`. Ps.: Não faz sentido usar uma parte `POO` e outra parte `procedural`.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, irei me atentar, é a primeira pergunta que faço no fórum, irei verificar as duas questões, muito obrigado, darei a resposta caso tenha resolvido ou não

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro, deu algum erro na sua consulta. Precisa pegar a mensagem de erro do log do apache.

Comment: Alterei a linha conforme sugestão do dvd, if($sql && mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0), conexão começou a validar e tive também que alterar o nome da tabela para minúsculo. Perfeito agora. Interessante como uma mudança de scripts local para online, a essas alterações.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema recentemente em uma hospedagem da hostgator. 
Tive que criar um arquivo php.ini e ativar a extensão na mão.
Tenta analisar se a dll do mysqli está ativada no php do seu servidor.
Espero que isso te ajude brother.