# Erro mysql: cada tabela derivada deve ter seu próprio alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Estou a tentar juntar duas tabelas `questionario` e `resposta` e selecionar da tabela `questionario` duas datas, este foi o código que eu experimentei em php:

```
$verificar=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT questionario.*, resposta.* from questionario 
JOIN resposta on questionario.pergunta_id=resposta.pergunta_id,
(select COUNT(pergunta_id) as total, classificacao from questionario 
where data BETWEEN '".$_POST["datainicial"]."' AND '".$_POST["datafinal"]."' 
group by classificacao");
        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verificar)) {...}
```

Porém ele retorna este erro:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Eu revirei a internet, e não encontro nenhuma solução.

Portanto experimentei o seguinte no phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT questionario.*, resposta.* from questionario 
JOIN resposta on questionario.pergunta_id=resposta.pergunta_id,
     (select COUNT(pergunta_id) AS total, classificacao from questionario where data 
BETWEEN '2018/06/07' AND '2018/06/08' GROUP by classificacao)
```

Como era de esperar a query não funcionou, ele retorna este erro

> Cada tabela derivada deve ter seu próprio alias...

Aqui se encontra a estrutura das tabelas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplos de alguns dados inseridos nas tabelas

Tabela questionario

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tabela resposta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce possui a estrutura das tabelas? Se puder posta-las fica melhor para ajudar.

Comment: Já alterei Clayton!

Comment: Olá Ana! Não percebi bem o que pretende, count de perguntas por classificação, juntamente com toda a infor de questionario e pergunta? Quais as colunas que pretende exatamente? o alias em falta deve se ao select do count, mas preciso de perceber o que se quer para solucionar ;)

Comment: Bom dia Ana, sim o que pretendo é juntar ambas as tabelas, retornar todas as informações, entre duas datas. **A query no phpMyAdmin já funciona**, ele retorna o que eu pretendo, porém no php aparece o seguinte erro `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ana, utilize essa query abaixo:

```
Select COUNT(questionario.pergunta_id) total,questionario.*, resposta.* from 
questionario 
JOIN resposta on questionario.pergunta_id = resposta.pergunta_id
Where questionario.data BETWEEN '2018-06-07' AND '2018-06-08'
group by questionario.pergunta_id
```

Resposta para o erro PHP:
[Erro no MySQL “expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)

Comment: Clayton, obrigada a query funciona perfeitamente no phpMyAdmin! Porém eu preciso que funcione em php, e obrigatoriamente necessito de um `count` para receber o total de `classificacao` como mostra na tabela questionario (na estrutura)..

Comment: O retorno no PHP utilizando a query que postei ainda da erro ou funciona? Voce pode postar alguns registros de exemplo  das duas tabelas para que eu possa fazer alguns testes?

Comment: Já alterei novamente Clayton! A sua query em PHP deu erro, porque no seguimento do meu código, eu necessito do "total" que supostamente se encontraria no  `(select COUNT(pergunta_id) as total, classificacao...`

Comment: Alterei a query para conter o total de respostas por pergunta Ana. Com realação ao erro no PHP caso persista, coloquei um link de uma pergunta já respondida com esse erro

Comment: Clayton, funcionou a sua query, e fui ver a resposta que você recomendou, e de facto o meu erro estava em "resposta" eu digitei mal!! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Que bom Ana! Por nada