# Dificuldade em imprimir linhas de uma tabela usando PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou fazendo um CRUD com PHP e MYSQL e dividi a pagina em varios blocos do codigos, cada um com um CRUD de cada tabela do meu BD, todos estão funcionando perfeitamente menos esse do codigo abaixo:

```
<div class="container">
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div class="well" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:auto; width:70%;">
    <span style="font-size:25px; color:#1f1a2f"><strong>Sorteio</strong></span> <!-- BOTÕES -->
    <span class="pull-right"><a href="#addnewPe" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Adicionar</a></span>
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Data pedido</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Funcionário</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Total do pedido</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido Pp INNER JOIN tb_cliente C ON Pp.codCliente = C.codCliente INNER JOIN tb_funcionario F ON Pp.codFuncionario = F.codFuncionario INNER JOIN tb_produto P ON Pp.codProduto = P.codProduto");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dataPedido']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nomeCliente']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nomeFuncionario']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['descricao']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['qtdVendida']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalPedido']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <span class="pull-center"><a href="#delPp<?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></span>
                    <p>_____</p>
                    <span class="pull-center"><a href="#editPp<?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></span>
                    <?php include('pedido/button.php'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['msgPp'])){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['msgPp']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        unset($_SESSION['msgPp']);
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php include('pedido/add_modal.php'); ?>
```

ele está dando erro no fetch array

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp\www\crud_oop\index.php on line 233

Desde já muito obrigado pela a ajuda! ^^

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)

Comment: certo segui o procedimento e descobri o erro

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)

Comment: Rodou a query fora, na tua IDE?

Comment: rodei sim, e funcionou normalmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **or die($conn->error)** para ver o que está errado

```
$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido Pp INNER JOIN tb_cliente C ON Pp.codCliente = C.codCliente INNER JOIN tb_funcionario F ON Pp.codFuncionario = F.codFuncionario INNER JOIN tb_produto P ON Pp.codProduto = P.codProduto");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die($conn->error)){
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) –