# mysqli_connect não conecta

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou com dificuldade de solucionar a conexão com o php e o BD

Na pagina do meu projeto ele apresta a seguinte mensagem:

*Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\wamp64\www\plha\Index.php on line 71*

essa parte do programa se refere a um slide de imagens que busca o caminho no BD

```
<div id="carouselSite" class="carousel Slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#siteModalWork" class="work">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Work it us</button>
        </a>

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php
                        $control_active = 2;
                        $control_position = 1;
                        $cal_carousel = "SELECT * FROM carousel ORDER BY id ASC";

                        $result_carousel = mysqli_query ($con,$cal_carousel) or mysqli_error($con);
                        while($row_carousel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_carousel)){
                            if($control_active == 2){?>
                                <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <?php
                        $control_active = 1;
                        }else{?>
                            <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="<?php echo $control_position;?>"></li><?php

                            $control_position++;
                        }}?>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php
                $control_active = 2;
                $cal_carousel = "SELECT * FROM carousel ORDER BY id ASC";
                $result_carousel = mysqli_query ($con,$cal_carousel);
                while($row_carousel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_carousel)){
                    if($control_active == 2){?>
            <div class=" carousel-item active">

                <img src="img/<?php echo $row_carousel ['imgCarousel']; ?>"  class="img-fluid d-block cover">

            </div><?php
                $control_active = 1;
                }else{?>
            <div class=" carousel-item">

                    <img src="img/<?php echo $row_carousel ['imgCarousel'];?>" class="img-fluid d-block cover">

                </div><?php
                }}?>


        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Mas tenho outras aplicações que se conecta com o BD que não obtêm resposta

a variável $con ela recebe a conexão por outro arquivo, o arquivo connect.php

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "plathanus";
    $con;

    $con = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$dbname) or mysqli_error($con);
```

alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in

Comment: por que não usa PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result_carousel = mysqli_query ($con,$cal_carousel) or mysqli_error($con);
```

Acredito que esqueceu do `die`:

```
$result_carousel = mysqli_query ($con,$cal_carousel) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

O erro que está aparecendo diz que o `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` espera uma variável do tipo `mysqli_result` e na verdade recebe uma do tipo booleano.

Esse `or` fez com que o `$result_carousel` fosse tratado como um boolean

Comment: Muito obrigado Ronaldo!

Answer (score -1):

Código refatorado para um melhor entendimento, utilizando PDO bem como a identificação de falhas através do método getMessage();

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=db_sistema;host=localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    if($pdo){
        echo "conexão efetuada com sucesso";
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Falhou a conexão: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Interesante! 
Sou novato em programação, e desconhecia esse metodo, no caso para eu usar esse pdo a variável $pdo seria a variável que eu ia chamar no myslqi_query?