# Consulta mysqli com erro

Tags: mysqli

estou atualizando meu sistema do mysql para o mysqli e não tô conseguindo fazer uma das consultas. Já tentei de mil maneiras diferentes mas o erro permanece. Deveria ser simples mas não tá funcionando. Alguém tem uma luz?

```
$resultadod = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM ferias 
                    where usuario_id = $usuario_id 
                    and date_format(fp.dt_inicio, '%Y-%m-%d') <= date_format('$d', '%Y-%m-%d')
        and date_format(fp.dt_fim, '%Y-%m-%d') >= date_format('$d', '%Y-%m-%d'");

                   $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadod);

                   $idd = $row["id"];
```

O erro é esse: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: não sei se isso resolve mas tá faltando fechar parênteses do `mysqli_query(`

Comment: Coloca a variavél `$con` dentro de `mysql_assoc`

Comment: Assim: $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($con, $resultadod); não deu certo... Na verdade eu só quero saber se traz resultados mas o mysqli_num_rows também funcionou....

Comment: Mudei toda a pesquisa e agora consegui! Valeu!!!!!!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)