# passar variavel para um select

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Gostaria de passar o valor da variável `$var` para dentro do select, mas dá o seguinte erro :

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\APOLLO\empresas.php on line 7
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
$var = $_POST['empresa'];

include 'php/db_connect.php';
$result_usuarios = "SELECT $var FROM usuarios ";
    $resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($connect, $result_usuarios);

    while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuarios)){

        echo "Categoria: " . $row_usuario['categoria'] . "<br>";

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erro no MySQL "expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28184/erro-no-mysql-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in)

Comment: Ignorando o fato de seu código é susceptível a sql code injection. qual o resultado de `echo $var`?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,
Falta aspas na sua query! Fica assim:

"SELECT '".$var."' FROM usuarios ";