# PHP retornar dados do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Estou tentando fazer um `select` no banco de dados para teste, esse `select` exibe os dados do usuário depois de inserir usuário e senha. O erro acontece depois do `select`:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP1\consulta.php on line 57

```js
<? php
if (@$_GET['go'] == 'consultar') {
  $user = $_POST['usuario'];
  $pwd = $_POST['senha'];

  if (empty($user)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-se.'); history.back();</script>";
  }
  elseif(empty($pwd)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-se.'); </script>";
  } else {
    $query1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '$user' AND SENHA = '$pwd'"));
    if ($query1 == 1) {
      echo "<table><tr><td>Login</td><td>Nome do Usuário</td><td>Senha do Usuário</td></tr>";
      while ($escrever = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {

        /*Escreve cada linha da tabela*/
        echo "<tr><td>".$escrever['usuario'].
        "</td><td>".$escrever['nome'].
        "</td><td>".$escrever['senha'].
        "</td></tr>";

      }
      echo "</table>";


    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('Usuário ou senha não correspondem!');</script>";


    }
  }

} ?>
```

```html
<?php require_once "config.php"; ?>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=description content="">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Cadastro com PHP</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cadastro">
    <form method="post" action="?go=consultar">
      <table id="login_table">

        <tr>
          <td>Usuário:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="txt" maxlength="15" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Senha:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="txt" maxlength="15" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nome:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="txt" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="txt" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Consultar" id="btn">
        </tr>

      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No while você precisa passar o resultado da consulta(`resource`) e não o número de linhas retornado pela consulta, crie uma variável para isso:

```
$query1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO ..."));

//código omitido ...

while ($escrever = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
```

Note que `$query` não receberá o retorno de `mysql_query()` e sim de `mysql_num_rows()` que é um inteiro. Evite encadear muitas instruções isso dificulta a detecção de erros, quando estiver escrevendo seu código lembre de usar [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) para exibir as mensagens de erro do banco.

Pode corrigir dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '$user' AND SENHA = '$pwd'"
$query1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($query1);
//código omitido ...
while ($escrever = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
```

Caso seja um projeto novo pense em trocar as funções mysql_* pelo PDO ou mysqli.

leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada.