# PHP + SQL UPDATE PROBLEMA

Tags: php, sql

Boa Madrugada pessoal.
Estou fazendo um quiz simples para a minha aula de web e estou com um problema para fazer um update no SQL via PHP. O database ta configurado certinho, o select funciona mas o update esta inerte no sistema. Sem mensagem de erro e não funcionando. Alguém pode me dar uma luz por favor? E aproveitando, como eu seleciono o id do usuario que está ativo na sessão?

```
    // Exibe número de respostas certas e total de perguntas
    echo "<div id='results'>Você acertou $totalCorrect / 5</div>";

    // Faz os pontos serem multiplicados por 10
    $totalpoints = $totalCorrect * 10;

    // Exibe o total de pontos ganhos
    echo "<div id='results'>Você ganhou $totalpoints PONTOS</div>";

    // Seleciona o usuario e exibe o saldo de pontos          
    $pontos = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM users WHERE idu=1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($pontos);
    $result_pontos = $row['points'];

    // Exibe o total de pontos acumulados
    echo "<div id='results'>Você tem $result_pontos PONTOS ACUMULADOS</div>";

    // Soma pontos acumulados mais os adquiridos          
    $soma = $result_pontos + $totalpoints;

    // Adiciona os pontos no banco de dados
    $sql = ("UPDATE users SET points='$soma' WHERE idu=1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: você poderia incluir a mensagem de erro que é mostrado?

Comment: Não possui mensagem de erro. Ele carrega a página e não atualiza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que verifiquei no update você apenas adicionou a variável $sql é necessário usar a função mysql_query para o procedimento ter efeito

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points='$soma' WHERE idu=1") or die(mysql_error();
```

Comment: Funcionou agora. Obrigado

Comment: Flw, Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Os erros mais difíceis de encontrar são os sutis.

Answer (score 3):

Não acontece nada porque o update não foi executado no banco. Apenas foi atribuido uma string com um comando sql a variável `$sql`, é preciso executar essa instrução com o mysql_query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET points='$soma' WHERE idu=1");
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

As funções mysql_* já foram depreciadas e obsoletas, se esse é um projeto novo, sugiro que use o mysqli ou PDO como API de conexão ao banco de dados.

Leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: Funcionou. Vou estudar mais sobre PDO.