# Puxar dados da db

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de puxar os dados da minha db. Mas não sei como conectar, já tem o arquivo da configuração, mas não sei como puxar para usar .

Arquivo de conexão:

```
<?php
   define('BD_USER', 'root'); // USE O TEU USUÁRIO DE BANCO DE DADOS 
   define('BD_PASS', 'oi'); // USE A TUA SENHA DO BANCO DE DADOS 
   define('BD_NAME', 'painel2'); // USE O NOME DO TEU BANCO DE DADOS 
   mysql_connect('localhost', BD_USER, BD_PASS);
   mysql_select_db(BD_NAME);
```

Código HTML:

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div style="background-image: url('');">
    <li><a href="#">Titulo</a>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tem a imagem da estrutura da minha db: http://i.imgur.com/8aTZIi1.png

Comment: Coloca o código do arquivo de configuração tbm. está usando o mysqli ou pdo?

Comment: É um projeto novo?

Answer (score 3):

Não é recomendado utilizar as funções mysql_* ela já cairam em desuso há muito tempo é recomendado utilizar em projetos novos o PDO ou mysqli.

Pode fazer da seguinte forma para listar todos os registro do banco, são necessários três passos, definição da consulta, execução no banco e extração do resultado.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assco($query)){
   echo $row['titulo'] .' - '. $row['link'] .'<br>';
}
```

### Leitura recomendada

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect("host","usúario","senha","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysql_fetch_assco($query)){
   echo $row['titulo'] .' - '. $row['link'] .'<br>';
}
?>
```

Em MySQLi é muito mais fácil de editar, na minha opnião.