# Erro ao salvar dados de formulário em php

Tags: php, html, mysql, formulário, sql-insert

Estou com problemas ao passar os dados de um formulário html para ser processado em um arquivo .php
Nenhuma mensagem de erro.`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="cadastro_aluno_exe.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Matrícula</td>
                <td><input name="matricula" type="text" size="50" maxlenght="50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td><input name="nome" type="text" size="50" maxlenght="50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data de Nascimento</td>
                <td><input name="data_nascimento" type="text" size="20" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nacionalidade do Aluno</td>
                <td><input name="nacionalidade" type="radio" value="brasileira">Brasileira
                    <input name="nacionalidade" type="radio" value="brasileira_nascida_no_exterior">Brasileira Nascida no Exterior
                    <input name="nacionalidade" type="radio" value="naturalizado">Naturalizado
                    <input name="nacionalidade" type="radio" value="estrangeira">Estrangeira
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>UF de Nascimento</td>
                <td><select name="estado">
                        <option value="#">&nbsp</option>
                        <option value="MT">MT</option>
                        <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estado Civil</td>
                <td><select name="estado_civil">
                        <option value="#">&nbsp</option>
                        <option value="solteiro">Solteiro</option>
                        <option value="casado">Casado</option>
                        <option value="outros">Outros</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Profissão</td>
                <td><select name="profissao">
                        <option value="#">&nbsp</option>
                        <option value="nenhuma">Nenhuma</option>
                        <option value="outros">Outros</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Religião</td>
                <td><select name="religiao">
                        <option value="#">&nbsp</option>
                        <option value="catolica">Católica</option>
                        <option value="nenhuma">Nenhuma</option>
                        <option value="outros">Outros</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Recebe escolarização<br/>em outro espaço</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="rec_esc_outro_espaco">
                        <option value="#">&nbsp</option>
                        <option value="sim">Sim</option>
                        <option value="nao">Não</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Aluno com deficiência, transtorno global do<br/>desenvolvimento ou altas habilidades/Superdotação</td>
                <td><input name="deficiencia" type="radio" value="sim">Sim
                    <input name="deficiencia" type="radio" value="nao">Não
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Recomendações Médicas</td>
                <td><textarea name="rec_medicas" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Cadastrar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$matricula = isset($_POST["matricula"]) ? $_POST['matricula'] : "[não informado]" ;
$nome = isset($_POST["nome"]);
$data_nascimento = isset($_POST["data_nascimento"]);
$nacionalidade = isset($_POST["nacionalidade"]);
$estado = isset($_POST["estado"]);
$estado_civil = isset($_POST["estado_civil"]);
$profissao = isset($_POST["profissao"]);
$religiao = isset($_POST["religiao"]);
$rec_esc_outro_espaco = isset($_POST["rec_esc_outro_espaco"]);
$deficiencia = isset($_POST["deficiencia"]);
$rec_medicas = isset($_POST["rec_medicas"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (matricula,nome,data_nascimento,
        nacionalidade,estado,estado_civil,profissao,religiao,rec_esc_outro_espaco,deficiencia
        rec_medicas) VALUES ('$matricula,'$nome','$data_nascimento',
                '$nacionalidade','$estado','$estado_civil','$profissao','$religiao',
                        '$rec_esc_outro_espaco','$deficiencia',
                                '$rec_medicas')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
    echo "Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!";
else 
    echo "Erro ao cadastrar aluno";
```

?>

Voltar

```
<?php
$server = "127.0.0.1:3306";
$database = "sistema_escolar";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
if(!$con)
{
    die('Não foi possível conectar ao servidor: '.mysql_error());
}
/* echo 'Conectado com servidor'; */ 

echo "<br/>";

$db = mysql_select_db($database,$con);
if(!$db)
{
    die('Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados: '.mysql_error());
}
/* echo 'Conectado com o banco de dados'; */
```

?>

Comment: Renan, por favor coloque também o código da pagina `.php`

Answer (score 1):

No inicio do seu arquivo php você esta tentando iniciar uma operação com o `operador ternário` porém está mal formatado;

```
$matricula = isset($_POST["matricula"]) ? $_POST['matricula'] : "[não informado]" ;
```

Esta operação ternária esta verificando se a variavel `$matricula` tem o mesmo valor do `$_POST['matricula']` porém você não armazenou nada na variavel anteriormente, logo ela ira retornar `false`.

você pode simplificar isto fazendo;

```
if (isset($_POST['matricula']):
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
else:
$matricula = 'não informado';
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber o erro retornado do banco use a função `mysql_error()`, pela sql parece ser um erro de sintaxe, falta uma virgula(`,`) na chamada do penúltimo campo.

```
INSERT INTO ... deficiencia rec_medicas)
virgula aqui --------------^
```

Para pegar erro de uma consulta:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua query está errada. Você não pode simplesmente passar as variáveis como se fossem parâmetros, então ao invés de fazer isso:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (matricula,nome,data_nascimento,      nacionalidade,estado,estado_civil,profissao,religiao,rec_esc_outro_espaco,deficiencia, rec_medicas) VALUES '$matricula,'$nome','$data_nascimento',               '$nacionalidade','$estado','$estado_civil','$profissao','$religiao',
'$rec_esc_outro_espaco','$deficiencia',
'$rec_medicas')";
```

Faça isso:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (matricula,nome,data_nascimento,        nacionalidade,estado,estado_civil,profissao,religiao,rec_esc_outro_espaco,deficiencia, rec_medicas) 
VALUES (' . $matricula . ',' . $nome . ',' . $data_nascimento .','. $nacionalidade . ',' . $estado . ',' . $estado_civil . ',' . $profissao . ',' . $religiao . ','. $rec_esc_outro_espaco . ',' . $deficiencia . ','$rec_medicas . ')";
```

Prefira utilizar [**parâmetros nas Queryes**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) e filtros ao pegar dados dos arrays $_POST, conforme citado **[aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal, além de faltar a "," antes de rec_medicas, segui os passos de utilizar parâmetros nas querys. O código corrigido:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$matricula = isset($_POST["matricula"]);
$nome = isset($_POST["nome"]);
$data_nascimento = isset($_POST["data_nascimento"]);
$nacionalidade = isset($_POST["nacionalidade"]);
$estado = isset($_POST["estado"]);
$estado_civil = isset($_POST["estado_civil"]);
$profissao = isset($_POST["profissao"]);
$religiao = isset($_POST["religiao"]);
$rec_esc_outro_espaco = isset($_POST["rec_esc_outro_espaco"]);
$deficiencia = isset($_POST["deficiencia"]);
$rec_medicas = isset($_POST["rec_medicas"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (matricula,nome,data_nascimento,
        nacionalidade,estado,estado_civil,profissao,religiao,rec_esc_outro_espaco,deficiencia,
        rec_medicas) VALUES ('.$matricula.','.$nome.','.$data_nascimento.',
                '.$nacionalidade.','.$estado.','.$estado_civil.','.$profissao.','.$religiao.',
                        '.$rec_esc_outro_espaco.','.$deficiencia.',
                                '.$rec_medicas.')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if($result)
    echo "Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!";
else 
    echo "Erro ao cadastrar aluno";
```

?>

Voltar

Comment: Se for um projeto novo escolha entre o mysqli ou PDO, as funções mysql_* são obsoletas, usadas em projetos legados. [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91) ,[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91) e
[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: sim, eu irei otimizar o código, obrigado pela observação.