# problemas na hora de mandar os dados para o banco de dados

Tags: php

Estou entrando agora na parte de programaçao com `mysql` e `php`, e estou com dúvida, na parte de chamar o banco de dados.vcs pode me ajudar?

Os códigos que escrevi:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> sistema de cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get="action="cadastrando.php">
nome: <input type="text" name="name"/> <b></b>
sobre nome: <input type="text" name="sobrenome"/><b> </b>
pais: <input type="text" name="pais"/> <b></b>
estado:<input type="text" name="estado"/> <b></b>
idade: <input type="text" name="cidade"/> <b></b>
e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/> <b></b>
senha: <input type="password" name="senha"/> <b></b>
<input type="submit" value=""/>
</form>

</body>
</html>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<html>
<head>
<title> cadastramento</html>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco= "cadastramento";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());
?>


<?php
$nome=$_post['NOME'];
$sobrenome=$_post['SOBRENOME'];
$pais=$_post['PAIS'];
$estado=$_post['ESTADO'];
$cidade=$_post['CIDADE'];
$email=$_post['EMAIL'];
$senha=$_post['SENHA'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usaname(NOME,SOBRENOME,PAIS,ESTADO,CIDADE,EMAIL,SENHA) values('$NOME','$SOBRENOME','$PAIS','$ESTADO','$CIDADE','$EMAIL','$SENHA')");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, sua pergunta está muito vaga e meio sem sentido. Poste os códigos que já tem e tente explicar melhor o que precisa.

Comment: Recomendaria separar a camada de visão com a camada que faz a conexão com o banco de dados para uma melhor organização.

Comment: A melhor dica para um iniciante me php, NÃO use as funções mysql_*, prefira o mysqli ou o pdo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que as variáveis definidas estão em minusculas e as passdas no insert em maiusculas, o php é case sensitive para variaveis, logo `$nome` é diferente de `$NOME`.

O nome da super global é `$_POST` em maiusculas mesmo.

O método de envio é definido no form

```
<form method="get="action="cadastrando.php">
```

Use `$_GET` para get e `$_POST` para post, sugiro que altera o `method` para post.

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usaname(NOME,SOBRENOME,PAIS,ESTADO,CIDADE,EMAIL,SENHA) values('$nome','$sobrenome','$pais','$estado','$cidade','$email','$senha')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)