# O que significa escalabilidade de software?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, terminologia, escalabilidade

Ouço muito se falar sobre que softwares precisam possuir escalabilidade em aplicações. Pesquisando sobre o assunto, encontrei a seguinte definição:

> **Significado de Escalabilidade:**
>
> Em engenharia de software, escalabilidade é uma característica desejável em todo o sistema, em uma rede ou em um processo, que indica sua habilidade de manipular uma porção crescente de trabalho de forma uniforme, ou estar preparado para crescer.
>
> **Exemplo do uso da palavra Escalabilidade:**
>
> *escalabilidade em startups é uma forma de acelerar o crescimento de uma empresa, com pequenos custos e de forma muito rápida.*

Na minha visão, este conceito ainda não ficou claro. Portanto, o que significa escalabilidade de software? Como aplicar isso na prática?

Fonte: http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/escalabilidade/13286/

Comment: Para esta questão, não há mais nada que precise ser melhorado. Fiz o aceite da resposta.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Escalar significa subir. Então a escalabilidade, neste contexto, é a capacidade de aumentar o tamanho do software ou do seu uso.

Quando falamos da escalabilidade do software em si estamos falando sobre ter um código e uma arquitetura que é fácil de dar manutenção, de aumentar suas funcionalidades, de várias pessoas trabalharem nele.

Eventualmente podemos usar o termo para indicar que o software pode ser usado por uma grande quantidade de usuários (clientes). No sentido de pessoas ou empresas.

A escalabilidade do uso tem a ver com a capacidade de aumentar o consumo de memória, de processos, atender demandas de alta exigência de processamento e possivelmente concorrência de acesso.

Existem inúmeras técnicas para possibilitar melhor escalabilidade de software.

Alguns softwares funcionam muito bem com baixa quantidade de dados ou acesso, mas quando isto aumenta, ele passa ter problemas. Não adianta por mais e melhores equipamentos. Seria uma solução paliativa.

Algumas coisas crescem linearmente e isto é bom, escala bem. Os problemas se dão quando o software cresce e as necessidades crescem exponencialmente. Ou seja, o aumento da necessidade gera um aumento da capacidade de forma proporcionalmente maior. É uma progressão geométrica.

Claro que o ideal seria ter uma progressão logarítmica, assim cada aumento da necessidade obriga um aumento da capacidade em uma proporção bem menor. Mas é raro conseguir isto em todo o software, a não ser em coisas pontuais do software.

Leia mais sobre isto em [Big-O](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O) ([em inglês bem melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Provavelmente o termo é usado em mais contextos do software.

Muitas vezes usamos o termo se referindo à solução como um todo e não apenas ao software. Aí escalabilidade tem a ver com a capacidade de atender bem a necessidade adicionando infraestrutura. Há casos que o software não está preparado para isto. Adicionar infra vai trazer outros problemas que o software não sabe lidar. Softwares escaláveis se adaptam a isto.

Softwares pouco escaláveis são mais vulneráveis à ataques.

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalabilidade). [Em inglês bem melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Escalabilidade como sinônimo de manutenabilidade (sua primeira definição do termo) não parece constar na Wikipedia. Mas entendo por que sejam intercambiados. A coisa a ser escalada pode ser tanta coisa que podemos muito bem estar falando da manutenção do software, não só do trabalho que ele executa.

Comment: O termo pode ser usado em muitos contextos até fora na nossa área. Podemos falar de escalar um projeto, dizer que 10 sub-projetos com 10 profissionais escalam melhor que 1 com 100. Se costuma dizer que código procedural não escala bem (o que não é verdade se for bem feito), que linguagens dinâmicas não escalam bem (que é uma verdade, mas exageram). Que o algoritmo tal não escala bem. Enfim, dá para achar um monte de exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo de escalabilidade:

Você tem uma empresa e quer se previnir de mudanças na leis, aumento de consumo e geração de dados. Então você arquiteta seu sistema para atender a estas mudanças com o menor impacto possível. Entra também o conceito de parametrização.

Por exemplo, cálculo de impostos, emissão de notas fiscais com cpf, etc, são mudanças que o sistema deve se comportar sem grandes problemas.