# O que é CQRS e como implementar?

Tags: c#, design-pattern

`CQRS` (Command and Query Responsibility Segregation) é uma dessas siglas que nos deparamos e não conseguimos compreender completamente seu significado e utilização.

O que é `CQRS` e como implementar?

Comment: Tem um artigo legal do Martin Fowler (em inglês) sobre isso. No rodapé tem o link para a tradução em português. https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: Também queria aprender CQRS, o problema não é ler, mas implementar.

Comment: Tem também esse [link](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2016/07/cqrs-o-que-e-onde-aplicar/) que é bastante esclarecedor sobre o assunto.

Comment: CQRS é a separação da leitura e escrita dos dados em dois *models* distintos (sendo *model* a definição de entidades e o relacionamento entre elas). Pode ser útil quando a necessidade de leitura dos dados (aqui, *"query"*) requer um design muito diferente das necessidades de escrita destes dados (aqui, *"command"*). Quando a leitura e escrita não exigem um design diferente mas você apenas precisa endereçar questões de performance ou de visões diferenciadas dos dados em algumas consultas, existem opções bem mais simples. Portanto acho que não vale uma descrição de *como* implementar CQRS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## CQRS

**C**ommand **Q**uery **R**esponsibility **S**egregation, ou CQRS, é um padrão de arquitetura de desenvolvimento de software que resume a separar a leitura e a escrita em dois modelos: **query** e **command**, uma para leitura e outra para escrita de dados, respectivamente.

[image: Reprodução / Mike Fowler]

- **Query model:** responsável pela leitura dos dados do BD e pela atualização da interface gráfica.
- **Command model:** responsável pela escrita de dados no BD e pela validação dos dados. Sua interação com a interface gráfica é somente receber os dados a serem escritos.

---

Hoje, [aplicações modernas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNNpXPCUH2U) tem conceitos novos de disponibilidade, performance, funcionalidade e usabilidade (estamos falando de aplicações de "escritório").

[image]

Seguinte tal estrutura, esse tipo de aplicação deve estar disponível em uma arquitetura pensada para suportar milhares de usuários, como pouquíssimos usuários (e claro, ainda nos padrões da estrutura moderna de aplicações). Querendo ou não, é um conceito de [ESCALABILIDADE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90297/o-que-significa-escalabilidade-de-software), o seu software/serviço seguindo o seu próprio uso.

> Quando falamos da escalabilidade do software em si estamos falando
>   sobre ter um código e uma arquitetura que é fácil de dar manutenção,
>   de aumentar suas funcionalidades, de várias pessoas trabalharem nele.
>
> Eventualmente podemos usar o termo para indicar que o software pode
>   ser usado por uma grande quantidade de usuários (clientes). No sentido
>   de pessoas ou empresas
>   [Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90310/41056)

Num exemplo simples: pensemos num saque no caixa eletrônico. Milhares de pessoas (e agora você) acessando o mesmo banco de dados, gravando e lendo dados a todo o tempo. Ignorando as filas, imagine se demorasse horas para fazer um único saque?! Um caos.

A respeito do CQRS, outra definição importante é: **nada é o que parece**. É, exatamente. Se você efetua uma consulta no banco de dados (query model) e por algum motivo esses dados forem alterados (command model), o que você vê não é necessariamente o dado atualizado. Trabalhar com esses dados sempre atualizados pode causar uma enorme perda de performance (lembrando, sua aplicação é moderna!).

A proposta de dividir as tarefas pode parecer um pouco mais interessante agora. Mas não, não é só isso, a segregação dos modelos diz respeito a separação **física e/ou lógica** dos dados.

---

Numa diagramação mais simples possível do CQRS, temos:

[image]

## Implementação

> Não existe uma única maneira de implementar o CQRS na sua aplicação,
>   pode ser feito de uma forma simples ou muito complexa, depende da
>   necessidade. Independente de como for implementado o CQRS sempre
>   acarreta numa complexidade extra e por isso é necessário avaliar os
>   cenários em que realmente são necessários trabalhar com este padrão. 
>   [Fonte](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2016/07/cqrs-o-que-e-onde-aplicar/)

## Exemplo de implementação

Daqui para baixo, um padrão CQRS simples. Já adianto, retirado [daqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/Mt147237.aspx).

**A arquitetura CQRS para um projeto ASP.NET MVC**

Crie alguns projetos de biblioteca de classes, pilha de consulta e pilha de comando, e faça referência aos dois do projeto de servidor da Web principal.

**A pilha de consulta**

A biblioteca de classes de pilha de consulta só está preocupada com a recuperação de dados. Ela usa um modelo de dados que corresponde aos dados usados na camada de apresentação o mais próximo possível. Você raramente precisa quaisquer regras de negócios aqui, pois elas se aplicam aos comandos que alteram o estado.

O padrão de modelo de domínio popularizado pelo DDD é essencialmente uma forma de organizar a lógica do domínio. Quando você faz consultas de front-end, você está lidando apenas com parte da lógica do aplicativo e casos de uso. A lógica de negócios do termo geralmente resulta da união de lógica específica do aplicativo com a lógica invariável de domínio. Se você souber o formato de persistência e o formato de apresentação, basta mapear os dados como faria em uma consulta do bom e velho ADO.NET/SQL.

É útil se lembrar de que qualquer código que você pode chamar da camada de aplicativo representa o domínio de negócios do sistema. Portanto, é a API invariável que expressa a lógica principal do sistema. Em condições ideais, você deve garantir que nenhuma operação inconsistente e incongruente seja possível mesmo por meio da API exposta. Então para impor a natureza somente leitura da pilha de consulta, adicione uma classe wrapper em torno do objeto de contexto do Entity Framework padrão para se conectar ao banco de dados, conforme mostrado no código a seguir:

```
public class Database : IDisposable
{
  private readonly QueryDbContext _context = new QueryDbContext();
  public IQueryable<Customer> Customers
  {
    get { return _context.Customers; }
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
   _context.Dispose();
  }
}
```

A classe Matches é implementada como uma coleção DbSet na classe base DbContext. Como tal, ela fornece acesso completo ao banco de dados subjacente e você pode usá-la para configurar consultas e atualizar operações por meio de LINQ às Entidades.

A etapa fundamental para configurar um pipeline de consulta é permitir o acesso ao banco de dados somente para consultas. Essa é a função da classe wrapper, onde Matches é exposta como um IQueryable. A camada de aplicativo usará a classe de wrapper do banco de dados para implementar consultas direcionadas em trazer os dados para a apresentação:

```
var model = new RegisterViewModel();
using (var db = new Database())
{
  var list = (from m in db.Customers select m).ToList();
  model.ExistingCustomers = list;
}
```

Agora há uma conexão direta entre a fonte de dados e a apresentação. Você está apenas lendo e formatando os dados para fins de exibição. Você espera que a autorização seja imposta na porta por meio de logons e restrições de interface do usuário. Caso contrário, você pode adicionar mais camadas ao longo do processo e habilitar a troca de dados por meio de coleções de dados IQueryable. O modelo de dados é o mesmo que o banco de dados e é de 1 para 1 com persistência. Esse modelo é às vezes chamado de árvores de expressão em camadas (LET).

Há algumas coisas que você deve observar neste momento. Primeiro, você está no pipeline de leitura em que as regras de negócios normalmente não existem. Tudo o que você pode ter aqui são filtros e regras de autorização. Essas são bem-conhecidas no nível de camada de aplicativo. Você não precisa lidar com objetos de transferência de dados ao longo do caminho. Você tem um modelo de persistência e contêineres de dados reais para o modo de exibição. No serviço de aplicativo, você acaba com o seguinte padrão:

```
var model = SpecificUseCaseViewModel();
model.SomeCollection = new Database()
     .SomeQueryableCollection
     .Where(m => SomeCondition1)
     .Where(m => SomeCondition2)
     .Where(m => SomeCondition3)
     .Select(m => new SpecificUseCaseDto
       {
         // Fill up
       })
     .ToList();
return model;
```

Todos os objetos de transferência de dados especiais no trecho de código são específicos para o caso de uso de apresentação que você está implementando. Elas são apenas o que o usuário deseja ver no modo de exibição Razor, que você está criando e as classes são inevitáveis. Além disso, você pode substituir todas as cláusulas Where com métodos de extensão IQueryable ad hoc e ativar todo o código na caixa de diálogo escrita em linguagem específica do domínio.

A segunda coisa a observar sobre a pilha de consulta é relacionada a persistência. Na forma mais simples de CQRS, as pilhas de comando e consulta compartilham o mesmo banco de dados. Essa arquitetura torna o CQRS semelhante aos sistemas CRUD clássicos. Isso facilita a adotá-lo quando as pessoas são resistentes a alteração. No entanto, você pode criar o back-end para que as pilhas de comando e consulta tenham seus próprios bancos de dados otimizados para suas finalidades específicas. Sincronizar dois bancos de dados, em seguida, torna-se a outro problema.

**A pilha de comando**

No CQRS, a pilha de comando diz respeito apenas a execução de tarefas que modificam o estado do aplicativo. A camada de aplicativo recebe solicitações da apresentação e organiza a execução enviando comandos no pipeline. A expressão "enviar comandos ao pipeline" é a origem de vários tipos de CQRS.

No caso mais simples, enviar um comando consiste em simplesmente invocar um script de transação. Esse dispara um fluxo de trabalho simples que realiza todas as etapas exigidas pela tarefa. Enviar um comando da camada de aplicativo pode ser tão simples quanto o código a seguir:

```
public void Register(RegisterInputModel input)
{
  // Push a command through the stack
  using (var db = new CommandDbContext())
  {
    var c = new Customer {
      FirstName = input.FirstName,
      LastName = input.LastName };
    db.Customers.Add(c);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Se necessário, você pode transferir o controle para a camada de domínio verdadeiro com serviços e o modelo de domínio onde você implementa a lógica de negócios completa. No entanto, usar o CQRS não vincula você necessariamente ao DDD e coisas como agregações, fábricas e objetos de valor. Você pode ter os benefícios da separação de comando/consulta sem a complexidade extra de um modelo de domínio.

## Mais links sobre implementação

- [MSDN, Command and Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn568103.aspx)
- [MSDN, CQRS Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx)
- [Greg Young, CQRS Documents](https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf)
- [Martin Fowler, CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)
- [.NET Coders, Padrões e CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)](http://netcoders.com.br/blog/padroes-e-cqrs-command-query-responsibility-segregation-parte-1/)

Comment: O pior é que o CQRS nao é nada disto. O autor reitirou 3 vezes que ele é somente que o padrão consiste em apenas separar leituras de escritas, mas nós programadores gostamos muito de ver complexidade onde ela nao existe e surgem artigos como os que consultou que misturam 1000 conceitos diferentes e destrocem a ideia original do padrão.

Comment: @Bruno Costa É ingenuidade dizer que o CQRS não é nada disso. Dizer que SÓ a separação da leitura e escrita, não renderia 50 páginas de documentação. É um assunto complicado. Se quisermos fontes oficiais, teremos somente um link e acabou. https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf

Comment: dessas 53 páginas, 5 dedicam-se a explicar o que é o CQRS (17 a 22). As restantes sao sobre outros assuntos.

Comment: Sendo a classe `RegisterInputModel` idêntica à `Customer` isto não seria uma forma de `DRY` visto que se há uma alteração na entidade `Customer` esta alteração teria que ser repetida na Model ?

Answer (score 6):

De acordo com o autor do padrão ele consiste apenas em separar as operações de leitura das operações de escrita.

> When most people talk about CQRS they are really speaking about
>   applying the CQRS pattern to the object that represents the service
>   boundary of the application. Consider the following pseudo-code
>   service definition.
>
> CustomerService
>
> `void MakeCustomerPreferred(CustomerId)`
>
> `Customer GetCustomer(CustomerId)`
>
> `CustomerSet GetCustomersWithName(Name)`
>
> `CustomerSet GetPreferredCustomers()`
>
> `void ChangeCustomerLocale(CustomerId, NewLocale)`
>
> `void CreateCustomer(Customer)`
>
> `void EditCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails)`
>
> Applying CQRS on this would result in two services
>
> CustomerWriteService
>
> `void MakeCustomerPreferred(CustomerId)`
>
> `void ChangeCustomerLocale(CustomerId, NewLocale)`
>
> `void CreateCustomer(Customer)`
>
> `void EditCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails)`
>
> CustomerReadService
>
> `Customer GetCustomer(CustomerId)`
>
> `CustomerSet GetCustomersWithName(Name)`
>
> `CustomerSet GetPreferredCustomers()`
>
> That is it. That is the entirety of the CQRS pattern. There is nothing
>   more to it than that…

Tradução

> Quando a maior parte das pessoas falam sobre CQRS elas realmente estão
>   falando em como aplicar o padrão CQRS a um objeto que representa a
>   camada de serviço duma aplicação. Considere a seguinte definição de
>   serviço.
>
> ...
>
> Aplicar o padrão CQRS resultaria em dois serviços
>
> ....
>
> É só isto mesmo. O padrao CQRS é sómente isso. Não há mais nada nele para
>   além disso...

[Fonte](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/) - O próprio criador do padrão escreveu este texto.

Answer (score 4):

Como a questão contem a tag C#, o material mais oficial que encontrei é:

- [Command and Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568103.aspx), contendo exemplos de como usar CQRS com C#
- [CQRS Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx), referências sobre CQRS

A princípio **CQRS** é ter **duas APIs**, uma para fazer **consultas**, e outra para **comandar** o sistema.

Acidentalmente (pesquisando sobre Groovy), descobri que isso está na [moda](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/software-trends-for-2017):

> Many microservices implementations will move away from their
>   REST/JSON beginnings and truly embrace event-driven architectures,
>   with the hardest problems being solved by Event Sourcing and CQRS
>   implementations.

Tradução:

> Muitas implementações de microserviços se afastarão de seus primórdios
>   REST/JSON e verdadeiramente abraçarão arquiteturas orientadas a
>   eventos, com os problemas mais difíceis sendo resolvidos por
>   implementações de Event Sourcing  e CQRS.

Qual a relevância da minha observação?

Resposta: **Event Sourcing**

O exemplo em C# sobre CQRS que você encontra ali no link do [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568103.aspx), parece bem orientado a Event Sourcing. Normalmente, elas são implementadas em  conjunto, CQRS e Event Sourcing.

> *The CQRS pattern is often used in conjunction with the Event Sourcing pattern.*

A razão disso não é pertinente neste momento (se por acaso estiver curioso, faça outra pergunta no StackOverflow). O problema é que Event Sourcing complica bastante a implementação do CQRS.
A própria documentação fala sobre disso:

> *The inherent complexity of the CQRS pattern when used in conjunction
>   with Event Sourcing can make a successful implementation more
>   difficult*

Agora, você quer saber como implementar CQRS, **com** ou **sem** Event Sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

Menos menos, quase nada...

CQRS nada mais é do que o disparo de ações através de eventos, sendo que estas ações são separadas entre comandos e queries.

Comandos são ações com efeitos colaterais, por que elas mudam o estado da aplicação (pense em escrever, alterar ou excluir algo). Geralmente, comandos não retornam nada, são fire & forget.

Queries, por outro lado, são apenas isso: pegar dados (de um banco de dados, de uma API, de um OCR tentando ler texto da parede do banheiro). Elas não tem efeito colateral, pois nunca escrevem nada.

Qual a vantagem disso (baseado em casos reais que uso)?

1. Facilita cache, pois eu sei que não preciso validar cache em queries (somente em comandos). Tenho um framework codeless C#/T-SQL que impede a execução de Stored Procedures se nenhuma tabela envolvida foi modificada desde a data que meu client diz ter a última versão (é muito fácil saber quais tabelas um Stored Procedure usa e qual a data de modificação de cada tabela sem o uso de triggers). Em um comando, eu posso mandar atualizar uma variável em memória que diz qual a última escrita para cada Stored Procedure (fazendo com que as queries decidam se vão pro banco ou não).
2. Ajuda no controle de interfaces baseadas em eventos (ex.: XAML) ou reativas (ex.: Flutter). Meus serviços ficam bem separados e eu posso prever com muito mais facilidade o que impacta minha interface. Por exemplo, em Flutter, posso escutar um Stream de uma lista de objetos qualquer que só vai rodar minha UI quando esta lista mudar. Sem um comando, esta lista nunca muda. Com um comando, aí sim eu posso chamar um serviço e invocar novamente a query (nada impede de um comando invocar um ou mais eventos). Então eu consigo definir muito mais facilmente o estado da minha app e conheço melhor dependências e sei exatamente quando há escrita e quando não há (sem escrita, não preciso ficar atualizando UI). Lembrou de BLoC pattern lendo isso? Poisé... a única diferença é que BLoC não tem distinção entre escrita e leitura.

Em C#, um bom exemplo de implementação de CQRS é o package Mediatr. Ele inclusive adiciona algumas coisas legais como pipeline (ex.: quero logar todos os eventos executados, sem precisar alterar a implementação dos handlers de eventos).

Agora, coloque um gerenciador de filas ou eventos aí no meio (pense RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, etc) e pronto, vc tem esse mecanismo todo escalável (ex.: você pode ter um comando que roda exclusivamente em um servidor à parte, mais parrudo... você pode separar leituras e escrita em banco de dados podendo implementar replication mais fácil (onde um banco escreve e replica para N outros bancos somente leitura, para melhorar (e muito) a performance)). O pattern é só uma idéia que abre potencial para implementações.

Event Sourcing são outros 500. Na minha opinião, não tem absolutamente nada a ver com CQRS (embora o fato de separar escrita de leitura facilita MUITO a implementação de EvSrc).

E é só isso... KISS.