# O que é um código escalável?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, escalabilidade

Escalabilidade está ligada ao crescimento, no contexto de código, tenho algumas dúvidas pertinentes.

- O que é um código escalável?
- A escalabilidade do código envolve mais de um aspecto ou somente a performance ou *design*?
- Um código com baixa coesão e fortemente acoplado não seria escalável?

Comment: não sei se responde a pergunta na totalidade mas vale dar uma lida **[nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90297/o-que-significa-escalabilidade-de-software)**!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Veja [O que significa escalabilidade de software?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90297/101) e depois esqueça tudo o que tem lá. Escalabilidade de código nada tem a ver com escalabilidade de aplicação. Estamos aqui (espero eu) falando de como é fácil o código crescer e ainda ser administrável. Em geral a escalabilidade de código tem a ver com escalabilidade de equipe, porque é raro um código ser muito grande e mantido por uma pessoa, mas é possível ser só sobre o código.

Escalabilidade de código nada tem a ver com performance da aplicação e nem mesmo diretamente com a produtividade do desenvolvimento, embora tenha uma ligação entre o código ser administrável e produtividade.

Algumas características de um código escalável:

- organizado
- bem documentado
- tem pouco ou nenhum [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101) não local (algo que afeta a aplicação toda), é [ortogonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101)
- tem [boas abstrações, mas é preciso cuidado com vazamentos que prejudicam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101)
- é [modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) (até mesmo quando usa OOP)
- é [coeso e não acoplado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)
- segue o [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) (geralmente)
- é [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), não ser cheio de ^C e ^V é só um detalhe, mas não pode exagerar
- usa [KISS e YAGNI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101) (sem exagero, o YAGNI pode se voltar contra você por não oferecer boas saídas em manutenção futura para colocar novas funcionalidades sem afetar o todo), não pode ser convoluto
- tem boas [nomenclaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101)
- acerta na [taxonomia e ontologia das coisas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276787/101)
- é [limpo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/101)
- é [elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/101)
- não é [verboso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173190/101)
- não faz [otimizações prematuras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101)
- enfim, é [legível e fácil de dar manutenção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101), é um código óbvio
- não é [orientado a modinhas](https://blog.daftcode.pl/hype-driven-development-3469fc2e9b22), tudo que tem nele serve a um propósito claro e necessário.

## Experiência

Código escalável só pode ser escrito por quem domina todos os aspectos do desenvolvimento, todos os mecanismos que serão usados, e por quem tem experiência, porque não é algo óbvio. É possível fazer isso por uma equipe menos experiente, mas só sob forte supervisão de gente muito experiente, a não ser que a equipe seja toda formada por gênios que já nasceram sabendo, que conseguem ver o futuro correto sem ter passado por algo parecido. A pessoa faz para funcionar, não para ser certo, para ser escalável, porque a pessoa nem sabe o que é isso, porque será necessário e como fazer para que escale.

Todo mundo com o tempo, ou passa escrever código mais escalável, ou deveria sair da área. Mas muitos códigos não são escaláveis porque não há comprometimento para isso, seja por falha do profissional, seja por demandas de prazo no curto período que são impostas.

Tenho percebido que alguns softwares não precisam ser escaláveis. O pessoal fala muito em manutenção, mas pouco se faz. Eu trabalho quase que só com manutenção, e parece que quase todo mundo trabalha quase que só com coisa nova, nunca vão dar manutenção nessas coisas? Talvez a modinha não deixe. Será que é tudo tão bom assim? Ou será tão ruim que é melhor abandonar?

## Ferramentas

Algumas linguagens ajudam o código ser mais escalável, por exemplo as de [tipagem estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). Claro que testes podem fazer um papel semelhante, mas não em tudo. Robustez ajuda não só na qualidade do código, mas também na escalabilidade do código. Códigos "descobríveis" são mais escaláveis. Por isso linguagens de tipagem dinâmica são boas para *scripts*. Nenhum problema as pessoas fazerem *scripts*, muitos problemas precisam deles, o problema é fazer software *enterprise* com *scripts*. E pior, usar técnicas como OOP em *scripts*. OOP ajuda escalar código se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo.

Certos padrões de programação resolvem certos problemas, mas podem criar outros. Quanto mais código escreve menos escalável ele é, a não ser que ele simplifique algo de forma contundente. Por isso também é possível linguagem de tipagem dinâmica ter lá sua chance de serem mais escaláveis em algum sentido. Nada que reflexão e geração de código não resolva nas linguagens de tipagem estática, o segundo não é muito usado por não ter muitas ferramentas prontas e dar um pouco mais de trabalho, mas deveria para escalar mais.

Exemplo do que pode não ser escalável em código: [*checked exceptions*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214768/101). Esse é um recurso que parecia bom. Por que só Java usa? E quase todo mundo usa mal. Porque não é escalável. Conforme o código cresce, a hierarquia vai ficando mais complicada e a pilha de chamadas de métodos vai ficando grande começa ter tanto combinação pra lidar que fica impraticável e ocorre o que todo mundo faz, trata genericamente. Isso se tornou tão popular que os exemplos do Java são ruins e aí contamina até outras linguagens e todo mundo usa exceção do jeito errado por causa desta praga.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Prazo no curto muitas vezes é o vilão que me separa de uma boa prática de codificação.

Comment: @AugustoVasques todos nós

Answer (score 0):

O que vcs estão falando chamo de manutenabilidade, que é a facilidade em manter / evoluir o código.

Escalabilidade normalmente está ligado à facilidade em atender uma demanda crescente de usuários simultâneos (sem alteração de código), apenas escalando máquinas ou containers (Docker / Kubernates).

Vejam a definição no link -> https://medium.com/@yuri.live/scalability-and-maintainability-of-mobile-and-other-applications-part-1-21e3d07dadeb