# Quantidade máxima de classes em Java

Tags: java, classes, eclipse

Estava fazendo alguns exercícios do curso e me surgiu uma pergunta.

Se eu criar um projeto no Eclipse e nele vou incluir minhas classes, supondo que cada classe é um exercício específico, cada um com seus próprios métodos.

Sei que as classes e convenções gerais servem para limitar a desordem e implementar uma estrutura bem arquitetada para que o código seja de fácil compreensão para manutenções e sua própria escalabilidade.

Mas, todavia, entretanto...

Existe um limite de classes que se pode incluir em um projeto Java no Eclipse? Ou se isso depende apenas das limitações de hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A princípio, não existe um "limite", isso depende da complexidade do seu sistema.

Imagine um banco (financeiro, no caso). Você tem diversos tipos de contas:

- corrente
- poupança
- investimento

Todas elas são derivadas de uma classe poupança, que é derivada de uma classe abstrata e mais uma dezena de outras classes.

Uma conta possui um proprietário. Esse proprietário pode ser:

- pessoa fisica
- pessoa juridica

E ambos são derivados de outras classes. Olha quantas classes tivemos até aqui.

As coisas ficam ainda mais complexas se usarmos interface gráfica, bancos de dados e as API's da Oracle/Sun/diabo a quatro. Um programa pode ter até algumas centenas de classes "por tabela".E isso não é, necessariamente, bom ou ruim, isso tudo depende da optimização do seu próprio código e do objetivo que ele deve cumprir. O único problema, como disse o usuário Maniero, é a capacidade do ser humano de lidar com tanta complexidade.

A imaginação (e a organização) é o limite...

Answer (score 6):

Não existe limite teórico, só prático. Nem mesmo hardware é o limite, qualquer um bem ruim poderá escalar bem qualquer projeto, não importa que seja o maior da história da humanidade, o problema real é a [escalabilidade humana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364945/101) de lidar com isto.

Código bem feito escala bem mesmo sem classes, código mal feito escala mal até, e principalmente, com classes.