# Banco de dados com php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta no banco de dados com o seguinte script:

```
<?php
        require("conexao.php");

        $exibir = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exibir)){
            $id = $r['id'];
            $nome = $r['nome'];
            $altura = $r['altura'];
            $peso = $r['peso'];
            $imc = $r['imc'];
        }    
?>
<?php
            echo "$nome <br/>";

?>
```

O código acima era para retornar todos os nomes da tabela, mas só me retorna o ultimo !

Gostaria que me retorne-se todos os nomes!!

O que está errado?

Comment: Já começou usando funções obsoletas e removidas das versões novas do PHP.

Comment: Você está fazendo um loop com o resultado, e no final está exibindo uma variável, logo, ela é o ultimo resultado porque o loop rodou todos eles. A última coisa adicionada em `$nome` foi o valor do último registro.

Comment: isso Samuel, use o mysqli_query() e mysqli_fetch_array() como o @rray citou.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que você está escrevendo o nome de fora do laço de repetição. O Termo "while" significa "enquanto" e representa uma estrutura de repetição. Neste caso

```
Enquanto houver registro no banco de dados, faça:
    Faça Alguma coisa
Fim Enquanto
```

Mova seu echo para dentro do laço.

```
    require("conexao.php");

    $exibir = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exibir)){
        $id = $r['id'];
        $nome = $r['nome'];
        $altura = $r['altura'];
        $peso = $r['peso'];
        $imc = $r['imc'];

        // Você deve escrever aqui o nome para aparecer todos os nomes.
         echo $nome . '<br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Para exibir todos os valores da tabela, deixa a instrução que imprime algo na tela(`echo`) dentro do while e não fora, do contrario apenas o último resultado será apresentado.

Código com problema:

```
 while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exibir)){
            $id = $r['id'];
            $nome = $r['nome'];
        }    
?>
<?php
            echo "$nome <br/>";
```

Código certo:

```
<?php
        require("conexao.php");

        $exibir = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exibir)){
            $id = $r['id'];
            $nome = $r['nome'];
            $altura = $r['altura'];
            $peso = $r['peso'];
            $imc = $r['imc'];
            echo "$nome <br/>"; //<---- aqui está a diferença
        }    
    ?>
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Answer (score 0):

Repare que você criou o while corretamente, porém como While esta percorrendo todos os registros do seu select, a sua linha `echo "$nome <br/>";` deve vir também dentro do while para que a medida que encontre um nome ele exiba este nome e assim fará com todos nomes encontrados

```
 <?php
    require("conexao.php");

    $exibir = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");

    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($exibir)){
        $id = $r['id'];
        $nome = $r['nome'];
        $altura = $r['altura'];
        $peso = $r['peso'];
        $imc = $r['imc'];

        echo "$nome <br/>";
    }               
?>
```