# Segurança na hora de criar uma função de consulta com PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, php-5

Estou migrando agora para o PDO por causa da segurança, mas não sei se estou utilizando corretamente o PDO.

Estou criando essas funções para tornar mais rápido o uso do PDO, mas não sei se essa forma é segura. É a mesma coisa de eu estar usando da forma sem função?

```
<?php 
    function Conecta(){
try{
    $conexao=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistemaescolar",'root','');
}
catch(PDOException $erro){
    $erro->getMessage();
}   
return  $conexao;
}

function ExecutaConsulta($conexao,$sql){
  $valor=func_get_args();
  $valores=array_slice($valor,2);
  $preparado=$conexao->prepare($sql);
  $preparado->execute($valores);
  $executar=$preparado->fetch();

  return $executar;

}
$conecta=Conecta();


$sql="SELECT * FROM se_professores WHERE id=?";
$resultado=ExecutaConsulta($conecta,$sql,1);
echo $resultado['nome'];

?>
```

Comment: Está tudo em dia com o seu código, as funções são uteis para reaproveitamento de código, vc n vai criar 5 conexões em 5 arquivos? uma função resolve ;)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. E não, não vou criar 5 conexões em 5 arquivos, estou substituindo o mysql... Então estou colocando isso no arquivo de conexão que passa por todas as partes do site, só misturei ai para ficar melhor

Comment: Só está faltando fazer o binding para tornar mais seguro as consultas etc.. Pode ter como referência: https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO

Comment: Blz. Vou ler a respeito

Comment: Acho que é uma boa pergunta de *code review* e pode servir de base para uma resposta canônica e possível alvo de futuras duplicatas. O que acha da edição que fiz, @rray?

Comment: ficou melhor, mais clara.

Comment: Migrando de qual lib para o PDO? E qual o DB a ser usado?

Comment: Do absoleto mysql

Comment: Provavelmente seria melhor mysqli então, se o que busca é segurança e eficiência (principalmente pelo fato do mysqli não simular binding por padrão, como o PDO faz, que é "fake" se não modificar o comportamento padrão). De qualquer forma, seja com um ou com outro, o importante é o escape correto das coisas antes de usar em queries. Só pra você entender a diferença, um binding verdadeiro manda a _query_ separada dos valores, o que elimina qualquer possibilidade de injeção. Um simulado depende de escape do lado do cliente. Além disso, só o bind nativo é eficiente para operações sequenciais.

Comment: @Bacco, poderia me elaborar uma resposta completa? porque ja ouvi falar disso sobre o PDO, mas não ficou totalmente claro. E estou me aprofundando mais recentemente. Essas questões que apontou no seu comentário seria de grande interesse acho que não somente para mim

Comment: @LocalHost isso já tem no site em algum canto, sobre as diferenças de PDO e mysqli_ - confesso que as respostas não estão explicando tão bem essa parte, mas é coisa que já tem no site.

Comment: Ok, vou procurar então :)

Comment: Segue o link. Tem uma resposta que eu até dei 50 pontos de bonus, pq o autor lembrou de explicar isso. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Análise do código

A sua implementação está correta, pois ao passar os valores de uma consulta como array para a função [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php), ela irá preparar os parâmetros recebidos tratando os todos como `PDO::PARAM_STR`, isto é, todos os parâmetros recebidos serão tratados como uma string e não terá riscos de sofrer uma Sql Injection, a não ser que os valores sejam concatenados antes em sua query.

No exemplo abaixo, utilizo um array como terceiro parâmetro, mas será explicado o motivo mais adiante.

```
 // Forma vulnerável
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $valor = $_POST['valor'];
 $query = 'INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (' . $nome . ', ' . $valor . ')';
 $resultado0 = executaConsulta($conecta, $query);

 // 1º Forma correta
 $query = 'INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)';
 $valores = array(
      ':name' => $_POST['nome']
      ':value' => $_POST['value']
 );
 $resultado1 = executaConsulta($conecta, $query, $valores);

 // 2º Forma correta
 $query = 'INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)';
 $valores = array(
      $_POST['nome']
      $_POST['value']
 );
 $resultado2 = executaConsulta($conecta, $query, $valores);

 // 3º Forma correta
 // A função filter_input é utilizada para acessar variáveis globais de forma mais segura.
 // Existem outras funções deste tipo. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.filter.php
 $query = 'INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)';
 $valores = array(
      ':name' => filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
      ':value' => filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'value', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
 );
 $resultado3 = executaConsulta($conecta, $query, $valores);
```

## Sobre query preparadas ou prepared statements

Alguns bancos de dados permitem utilizar um recurso de reaproveitamento de consultas. Seria algo como preparar um texto onde apenas algumas palavras mudam, e cada vez que for utilizar esse texto, é necessário informar apenas quais são as novas palavras.

Entretanto, nem todos os banco de dados suportam este recurso ([hoje não é mais o caso do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)), e como o PDO tem como objetivo ser uma interface prática para uso de vários drivers de banco de dados, tiveram que implementar uma maneira que este recurso pudesse ser utilizado quando necessário. Para resolver este problema, o recurso é simulado pela função.

[Na documentação existe estes exemplos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// Inserindo uma linha
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// Inserindo outra linha com diferentes valores
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

### Forçando o PDO a usar queries preparadas nativas

Para forçar o PDO a sempre utilizar o recurso de queries preparadas nativas, adicione logo após iniciar a conexão:

```
$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

O PDO possui tratamento para se caso ocorra um erro, a versão emulada seja utilizada, porem existem algumas desvantagens em utilizar o [recurso nativo em algumas versões](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/apr/using-pdo-mysql/)

- Não tiram vantagens do cache resultando em perda de performance;
- Não podem ser executadas por alguns tipos de queries como "SHOW TABLES";
- Não comunicam bem com o tamanho de colunas em outras queries que usam "SHOW" retornando resultados distorcidos.
- Chamar várias vezes procedurespode causar perda de conexão.

Algumas informações complementares em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not

### Binding de valores e variáveis

No PDO existem dois métodos que permitem associar parâmetros às suas queries, sendo elas o [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) e [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

O `bindParam` associa o nome de uma variável ao parâmetro da query, isto é, se o valor de uma variável for alterado e o método `execute` for chamado novamente, a query será executada com o novo valor.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name) VALUES (:name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

// Inserindo uma linha
$name = 'one';
$stmt->execute();

// Inserindo outra linha com diferentes valores
$name = 'two';
$stmt->execute();
```

Já o `bindValue` atribui um valor específico a um parâmetro de sua query, ou seja, para mudar o valor do parâmetro terá que chamar o método `bindValue` novamente.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name) VALUES (:name)");

// Inserindo uma linha
$stmt->bindValue(':name', 'one');
$stmt->execute();

// Inserindo outra linha com diferentes valores
$stmt->bindValue(':name', 'two');
$stmt->execute();
```

Em ambos os métodos é possível especificar qual o tipo deve ser utilizado para tratar o valor do parâmetro da query. O `bindParam` alem do tipo tambem é possível indicar outras opções como o tamanho máximo do valor.

## Sugestões de melhorias

### Melhoria no estilo de código

Recomendo dar uma lida na tentativa que a comunidade PHP tem feito de padronizar algumas coisas, a [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) é um guia de como melhor formatar seu código. Melhorar este modelo é um bom ponto para começar a observar o que seu código pode melhorar e irá lhe auxiliar a encontrar tanto as falhas de segurança quanto alguns bugs.

### Organização de parâmetros

Ao usar os parâmetros de forma "mágica" usando a função `func_get_args()` você terá problemas ao documentar, pois a assinatura de sua função não deixa explícito que é possível passar mais argumentos, isso deixará outros desenvolvedores confusos com seu código.

No código apresentado, não há a necessidade de a função receber infinitos parâmetros, pois a única coisa que o código da função realiza é obter um array de tudo que foi passado, retirando o que já é conhecido.

Para tornar a assinatura mais clara, você poderá definir um terceiro parâmetro com um valor padrão, no caso um array vazio, pois a função `execute` do PDO espera um array.

```
// Versão reescrita
function executaConsulta($conexao, $sql, $valores = array()){
    $preparado = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $preparado->execute($valores);
    $resultado = $preparado->fetchAll();

    return $resultado;
}
```

Na função também troquei a função [DOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) pela função [DOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php), pois assim sua função sempre retornará todo o resultado obtido em um array. Trabalhar com array é muito mais fácil do que com os objetos do PDO.

### Utilização da função

Ao utilizar a função, deixará mais claro se utilizar chaves no lugar do caractere curinga (?) assim como evitará que necessite passar o mesmo valor duas vezes, caso seja utilizado em dois lugares de sua query. Veja as duas possibilidades de uso:

```
// 1º forma
$sql = "SELECT * FROM se_professores WHERE id = ?";
$resultado1 = executaConsulta($conecta, $sql, array(1));

foreach ($resultado1 as $linha) {
    echo $linha['nome'];
}

// 2º forma
$sql = "SELECT * FROM se_professores WHERE id = :id";
$valores = array(':id' => 1);
$resultado2 = executaConsulta($conecta, $sql, $valores);

foreach ($resultado1 as $linha) {
    echo $linha['nome'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Olha tudo depende de que forma `ExecutaConsulta` vai ser utilizada. Caso seja como no seu exemplo:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM se_professores WHERE id=?";
$resultado=ExecutaConsulta($conecta,$sql,1);
```

não há nenhum problema óbvio de segurança, contudo nada no seu código impede chamadas deste tipo:

```
$userId = "1; DROP TABLE se_professores"; // user input com evil SQL Injection
$sql="SELECT * FROM se_professores WHERE $userId";
$resultado=ExecutaConsulta($conecta,$sql);
```

Então a resposta é que não há nada errado com sua função e ao mesmo tempo ela não garente um "uso seguro" do PDO.

Outra coisa, talvez você esteja usando apenas para testes o `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistemaescolar",'root','');` mas de qualquer forma é sempre bom lembrar, **nunca use o usuário root da database em produção e nunca largue um usuário sem senha na database de produção**.

Comment: Sim, é só para teste, apenas servidor local, no meu servidor on line possui usuario e senha sim.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer, porem haveria problema neste uso?    ExecutaConsulta($conecta,"SELECT * FROM se_turmas WHERE id=?",$idTurma);
Pois, não estou passando variável nenhuma no sql, nunca passo... Pois o exemplo de uma injeção sql, seria no caso de uso de passagem de variaveis no proprio sql correto?

Comment: Como eu disse na resposta (talvez não tenha ficado claro, vou ver se edito) se você sempre usar da forma como está seu exemplo não há problema algum, o que eu quis deixar claro é que a sua função ExecutaConsulta não previne alguém de fazer uma query de tal forma que ela fique vulnerável a ataques, como no caso do meu exeplo com SQL injection.

Comment: Blz, entendi agora

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma (e mais recomendável) é a utilização correta do PDO. Embora seja um pouco mais trabalhosa para implementar, garante uma maior segurança no momento de executar a query. Isso porque o processo é feito em duas partes.

1) Criamos o modelo da query. Esse modelo nada mais é do que um molde do que será a query. Diferentemente dos demais métodos, você não vai inserir a variável em si neste momento. Vai apenas indicar em que lugar a variável será colocada. No caso, será logo após o "...nome =".

```
$var = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela where nome = :nome');
```

2) Agora indicamos qual o valor vai ocupar o espaço indicado por ":nome":

```
$var->bindValue(':nome', 'Nome da pessoa');
```

No final o código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crud', 'root', '');
$var = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela where nome = :nome');
$var->bindValue(':nome', 'Nome da pessoa');
$run = $var->execute();
$result = $var->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Existe também outra maneira. Uma forma mais rápida (mas não a mais indicada) é remover caracteres especiais das variáveis que serão utilizadas na query. Sem utilização de ";" (ponto-e-vírgula) e "'" (aspas - simples ou duplas) e demais caracteres especiais é praticamente impossível executar o sql injection.

Veja o exemplo:

```
$password = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]_]/', '',$senha);
```

Se quiser mais informações:> http://www.devmedia.com.br/evitando-sql-injection-em-aplicacoes-php/27804