# É possível eu passar um array ou o POST como parâmetro e salvar no banco de dados sem precisar colocar em variáveis locais?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um formulário com dados pessoais do cliente e queria enviar esses dados para um class que possui um método que salva os dados no banco de dados, mas o formulário é muito grande e eu queria mandar um array ou o próprio POST, mas não queria ficar quebrando isso em variáveis, mandar o array inteiro para o banco.

```
$res = $cliente->cadastrar_cliente($_POST['name'],$_POST['cpf_cnpj'],
            $_POST['name_fan'],$_POST['zip_code'],
            $_POST['city'],$_POST['state'],$_POST['street'],
            $_POST['complement'],$_POST['district'],$_POST['district'],
            $_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['telefone'],$_POST['celular'])
```

Estou mando desse jeito, isso ta na view, queria mandar algo menos "feio" para não deixar a view bagunçada.

```
function cadastrar_cliente(
            $nome_responsavel, $cpf_cnpj = null, $nome_fantasia, $cep, 
            $cidade,$uf,$rua, $complemento,$bairro,$numero,$email, $senha, $telefone = null, $celular)

        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->open_connect("db_forpaper");

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (nome_responsavel,cpf_cnpj,nome_fantasia,cep, 
            cidade,uf,rua,complemento,bairro,numero,email,senha,telefone,celular) 
            VALUES ('$nome_responsavel', '$cpf_cnpj', '$nome_fantasia', '$cep', '$cidade', 
            '$uf','$rua','$complemento','$bairro','$numero','$email','$senha','$telefone','$celular')";

            $insert = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute();
            if($insert){
                $res = "ok";
            }else{
                $res = "erro";
            }
            return $res;
        }
```

Assim eu pego na minha class com o método de cadastro.

```
function cadastrar_cliente($_POST)

        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->open_connect("db_forpaper");

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (nome_responsavel,cpf_cnpj,nome_fantasia,cep, 
            cidade,uf,rua,complemento,bairro,numero,email,senha,telefone,celular) 
            VALUES ($_POST)";

            $insert = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute();
            if($insert){
                $res = "ok";
            }else{
                $res = "erro";
            }
            return $res;
        }
```

Queria algo assim para evitar ficar criando um array enorme ou quebrando ele em variáveis locais.
E eu queria uma opinião, este jeito que estou fazendo está muito errado? sou estagiário e esse é meu primeiro sistema que faço sozinho.

Comment: Não vou escrever como resposta pois o código só funciona com MySql(MariaDB não funciona) e a engine tem que ser InnoDB. Supondo as propriedades de `$_POST` estejam em mesma quantidade que as colunas de sua tabela e os nomes da propriedades sejam os mesmos das colunas de sua tabela você pode inserir como JSON: `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente VALUES ({json_encode ($_POST)})";`

Comment: Se usasse Prepared Statment, que inclusive é mais seguro do que o que está fazendo atualmente, poderia simplesmente fazer algo como `$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss", ...$_POST)`.

Comment: Sim sim, eu fiz desse jeito, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer deixar isso menos feio, porque não utiliza o PDO com curingas? Isso deixa até sua aplicação mais segura. Você pode ler sobre isso [aqui](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php). E tem um exemplo bem legal de outra pessoa [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/seguran%C3%A7a-na-hora-de-criar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-consulta-com-pdo).