# Como editar HTML num editor WYSIWYG (TinyMCE) e salvar no banco?

Tags: php, html, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

Atualmente tenho um blog sobre programação criado por mim e estou usando o editor TinyMCE para criar o conteúdo.
Uso específicamente o TinyMCE porque ele tem um plugin gratuito para upload de imagens, o que facilita muito a criação de postagens com imagens, o único problema é que as vezes eu preciso publicar no conteúdo do post um trecho de HTML de exemplo e ao salvar o POST tudo fica bem, mas na hora de editar a coisa desanda, o TinyMCE entende o HTML de exemplo como HTML de "verdade" e acaba mostrando o conteúdo renderizado, e não o código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O editor TinyMCE antes de ser um editor de "texto rico" é um formulário normal, então se quer editar você deve converter o `<` e `>` para `&lt;` e `&gt;`, como no exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'#texto' });</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = 'SELECT postagem FROM tabela WHERE id=1';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $variavelDoBanco = $row["postagem"];
    }
}
?>

  <form method="POST" action="arquivo.php">
  <textarea id="texto" name="texto"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($variavelDoBanco); ?></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nota se for usar Laravel com Blade não será necessário usar `htmlspecialchars`, pois o `{$var}` já codifica, segue um exemplo:

- Controlador:

  ```
  <?php
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  class HomeController extends Controller
  {
      public function editar()
      {
          return view('editor', [ 'postagem' => '<b>foo</b> bar <s>baz</s>' ]);
      }
  }
  ```
- Template editor.blade.php:

  ```
    <form method="POST" action="/editar">
    <textarea id="texto" name="texto">{$postagem}</textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
    </form>
  ```

> Nota sendo PHP eu usei a API `mysqli` a antiga api `mysql_` esta descontinuada e foi removida no PHP7
>
> Documentação da API antiga que informa isto:
>
> - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
>
> Links uteis:
>
> - [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/3635)
> - [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)
> - [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/3635)
> - [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

Comment: **POR FAVOR**, justifique o downvote... é porque eu respondi uma pergunta que esta na fila de analise? **POR FAVOR** se tem algo errado me explique pra eu melhorar

Comment: Acho que entendi, parece justo sim o downvote, vou editar... Só gostaria que explicassem os downvotes, eu realmente nunca fico chateado, desde que expliquem... Eu nunca fiquei de birrinha (devolvi) porque tomei downvote quando me explicam o motivo

Comment: Pronto editei, não sei qual linguagem o AP usa, mas se editar e informar depois eu edito com outro exemplo. O que me deixa chateado é a pessoa vir dar o downvote, achar que sou uma pessoa que fica de birrinha e não me informar o problema da resposta... Por favor entenda, eu sou um dos que mais apoia o modelo do Stack Overflow, se o downvote é justo eu vou concordar totalmente e não vou ficar atacando ninguém... A ideia é sempre melhorar se estiver ruim.

Comment: Reverti o downvote e dei up, estava saindo para almoçar e acabei esquecendo de comentar, mas a resposta não fazia o mínimo sentido com a pergunta antes.

Comment: @LuisHenrique obrigado por comentar :) - Acho que eu consegui entender o problema, se tiver algo mais que eu possa melhorar ou que você acha que esta errado pode negativar e comentar, isso faz parte do sistema e eu prometo tentar corrigir o que for possível!

Comment: Só pra complementar, estou usando Laravel, mas acredito que essa informação não seria relevante considerando o teor da pergunta.
Então pra pegar o post eu uso:
$post = Post::find($id);

Comment: @Neimeg vou postar um exemplo de Laravel, só me diz a versão. Note que o blade não precisa pois ele usa uma função chamada `e`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, é o Laravel 5.2

Comment: @Neimeg faz algum tempo que não uso Laravel, mas acredito que tenha ficado correto, se algo estiver errado por favor me informe.