# Qual é mais seguro PDO ou mysqli_*?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, segurança

Estava lendo e vi que muitos dizem, que `PDO` apenas simula os `prepared statements` e consideram uma desvantagem, gostaria de saber então... Qual é mais seguro? Ou qual é mais suscetível a `SQL Injection` ou qualquer outro tipo de tentativa de invasão?

Comment: Suscetível ou não depende mais de você do que da diferença entre PDO ou MySQLi. Mas, em resumo o MySQLi aparenta ser ligeramente mais seguro e mais rápido, afinal ele apenas foi feito para o MySQL e apenas suporta MySQL (enquanto o PDO suporta vários bancos). Veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar.

Comment: Apesar de ter besteira nas respostas da outra (por exemplo, apresentar prepare do lado do cliente como vantagem, sendo que é uma baita desvantagem), a pergunta é duplicata. Em resumo, pra MySQL nem tem comparação, o negócio é usar mysqli_ . Pra quem quer outros bancos, o PDO é a unica opção, caso não tenha driver nativo pro banco usado.

Comment: Os dois são seguros, mas com PDO você terá melhor portabilidade. Não é raro um projeto resolver mudar de banco e se você estiver usando mysqli, irá enfrentar de semanas até meses para realizar essa migração.