# Segurança de conexão com MySQL usando PDO, estou fazendo certo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, segurança

É seguro me conectar com o MySQL apenas usando a seguinte forma abaixo?

```
<?php

function conectar() {

        $server = "localhost";
        $dbname = "banco";
        $dbuser = "usuario";
        $dbpass = "senha";

        try {

                $con = new PDO ("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

        }catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo "ERRO GERADO" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $con;

}

?>
```

Posso usar apenas assim em minhas aplicações ou devo tomar mais algum cuidado?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

O problema da segurança não está na conexão, está na utilização geral. O maior problema que maioria das aplicações tem diretamente relacionadas ao banco de dados é a [injeção de SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101), então é na consulta que mora o perigo.

Existe uma quantidade enorme de problemas de segurança que podem afetar o banco de dados mas não está nele em si. Eu diria que mais de 90% dos sites por aí estão vulneráveis. Segurança é uma questão séria, difícil, que vai muito além do conhecimento básico de programação que a maioria tem. Eu tenho 35 anos de experiência e sou ruim em segurança. Tem quem passou pouco de 35 dias e acha que consegue fazer algo seguro. Morre afogado quem acha que sabe nadar, o que não sabe não nada.

É óbvio que a senha exposta assim é insegura, nunca deveria ter uma senha exposta deste jeito. O correto é sempre deixar o usuário digitar a senha e transportá-la e manipulá-la de forma segura o que envolve muita coisa pra falar aqui. Mas quase ninguém faz isto. Em alguns casos não dá para exigir isto, pode ser que um usuário não faça o *login* para poder acessar o banco. Uma criptografia já ajudaria um pouco nestes casos.

Claro que a senha exposta assim só é comprometida se outra pessoa entrar no servidor, então a insegurança vem de outra insegurança. Pode ocorrer por uma invasão externa, por acesso indevido local que é relativamente fácil ou até porque deixou alguém acessar distraidamente.

Precisa se perguntar porque está usando PDO. Se acha que é seguro, está enganado. Ele não dá segurança alguma. Ele serve para abstrair acesso a bancos de dados diferentes, o que ninguém faz, então normalmente é só uma camada inútil para quase todos os casos onde ele é usado.

Comment: Então não preciso me preocupar com a conexão em si e sim nas operações que usam ela certo?

Comment: Não é que não precisa se preocupar, mas que aí é difícil dar problema. Eu já vi quem deixou esta parte insegura, mas era um "gênio" :)