# Qual conexão com o banco de dados é melhor?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, conexão

Começei a trabalhar e estou atualizando o sistema da empresa, ela usa atualmente essa conexão:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("0.0.0.0", "teste", "teste", "teste");
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("<br> Nao foi possivel conectar. Erro: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$database_host = "0.0.0.0";
$database_user = "teste";
$database_password = "teste";
$database_db = "teste";

$conexao = new mysqli($database_host, $database_user, $database_password, $database_db);
mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8");
if ($conexao->connect_error) {
    die("A conexão falhou!");
}
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
```

Eu aprendi e uso esse tipo:

```
class ConexaoBanco extends PDO {

    private static $instancia = null;

    public function ConexaoBanco($dsn, $usuario, $senha) {
        //Construtor da classe pai PDO
        parent::__construct($dsn, $usuario, $senha);
    }

    public static function getInstancia() {
        if (!isset(self::$instancia)) {
            try {
                // Cria e retorna uma nova conexão
                self::$instancia = new ConexaoBanco("mysql:dbname=teste;host=0.0.0.0", "teste", "teste");
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Erro ao conectar o banco de dados!';
                exit();
            }
        }
        return self::$instancia;
    }
}
```

Qual dos dois é melhor? Porque?

Comment: PDO e Mysqli são duas APIs diferentes, PDO pode se comunicar com mysql e com outros bancos, já o mysqli é exclusivo para mysql, note que ambos tem diferenças de uso, esta pergunta é bem detalhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe melhor ou pior, neste caso, pois você utiliza o banco mysql. Se você utilizasse um outro banco, como PostgreSQL, você precisaria usar o PDO. Pois o `PDO` suporta mais bancos, enquanto o `mysqli` suporta apenas o banco mysql.

Existe um debate de qual é melhor ou pior. ([aqui por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar))

Mas, ao meu ver ambos tem muita segurança e performance. Se você está acostumado a usar o PDO, vá em frente e continue.