# MySQL - Consulta recursiva entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql

Situação: 
Dada a tabela perfil (Figura 01) , que descreve a quantidade, o tipo e o ano das questões (Figura 02) para o questionário (Figura 03), trazer q quantidade de questões, sendo que a quantidade especificada na tabela perfil seja de forma aleatória, sem repetir e na sequência descrita pela tabela apresentando o questionário

Como montar isso usando recursividade? percorrendo o perfil e filtrando as questões?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei o seguinte código sem sucesso:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(CatParent.id, Questoes.id) id, 
    COALESCE(CatParent.enunciado, Questoes.enunciado) enunciado,
    perfil.tipo_id
  FROM perfil
  JOIN Questoes ON perfil.tipo_id = Questoes.tipo_id and
       Questoes.ano_id = perfil.ano_id
  LEFT JOIN Questoes AS CatParent ON Questoes.tipo_id = CatParent.id
ORDER BY RAND( )

group by id, enunciado, tipo_id
```

Comment: Primeiro, as funções [`myslq_`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579) estão obsoletas, use [PDO ou `mysqli`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302). Segundo, mostre o que já fez do seu código. Terceiro, acredito que sua dúvida está mais relacionada ao SQL do que a parte de PHP, deixe o seu problema claro, foque na dificuldade que está com dificuldade

Comment: Guilherme, eu nunca usei recursividade, vou tentar explicar com mais calma o problema. Preciso percorrer cada linha da tabela perfil, nela preciso buscar as quantidades de questões conforme tipo é ano para montar o questionário, essas questões obviamente não se repetem nesse questionário. Como se fosse um laço, enquanto houverem tuplas em perfil, busque a quantidade de questões de acordo com o tipo é o ano, pensei numa query dando um select em questões  trazendo um limit de cada tuplas em perfil. As questões seriam sorteadas aleatoriamente   obedecendo tipo é o ano. Ficou mais claro a ideia?

Comment: Poste o que já tentou, seu código

Comment: Segue o codigo: [code] SELECT 
    COALESCE(CatParent.id, Questoes.id) id, 
    COALESCE(CatParent.enunciado, Questoes.enunciado) enunciado,
    perfil.tipo_id
  FROM perfil
  JOIN Questoes ON perfil.tipo_id = Questoes.tipo_id and
       Questoes.ano_id = perfil.ano_id
  LEFT JOIN Questoes AS CatParent ON Questoes.tipo_id = CatParent.id
ORDER BY RAND( )

group by id, enunciado, tipo_id[/code]