# Como buscar login de usuário para buscar dados em banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, login

**Bom noite pessoal,** eu estou usando essa linha de comando, funcionou perfeitamente comigo digitando o login da pessoa, mas quando tento por para ir com base no 'user_login'(usuário logado) ele nao vai a pagina nem chega a carregar quando tento, ja tentei usar até isso aqui:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

$username = $user_info->user_login;
```

Porém nao adiantou, poderiam me ajudar?
segue o código da pagina:

```
?php

$host = "xxxx";
$db   = "xxx";
$user = "zzz";
$pass = "sddss";

$con = mysqli_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

mysqli_select_db($db, $con);

$query = sprintf("SELECT valor FROM investimentos WHERE login= 'mirthrandir' ");

$dados = mysqli_query($query, $con) or die(mysqli_error());

$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);

?>


    
    Teste


?php
    // se o nÃºmero de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
            ?=$linha['valor']?> /
?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sugiro que antes de resolver esse problema troque de biblioteca de comunicação com o banco. As funções [`mysql_` estão obsoletas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579), use [`mysqli_` ou `PDO`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302)

Comment: sim sim eu ja fiz a alteração  vlw pela dica ^^

Comment: Já que fez a mudança, atualize o código da pergunta

Comment: Atualizado, mas nao sei se esta correto, sou buscando melhorar

Comment: Obrigado nao percebi que enviei com os dados.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro? Use isso aqui após abrir a tag php pra exibir as mensagens de erro. ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqi_select_db() in /home/fastinv1/public_html/teste.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/fastinv1/public_html/teste.php on line 14 esse erro ai.