# Meu primeiro sistema de cadastro e login não funciona, qual é o erro?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Quando vou entrar na página para realizar o cadastro, ele já exibe a mensagem "Esse login já existe" e não me deixa sequer inserir os dados. Creio que o erro está no PHP, mas não sei onde.

Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver, também não implementei nenhum sistema de segurança pois estou aprendendo e não sei se existem outros erros no codigo.

Esse é o codigo do cadastro:

```
<?php 

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = MD5($_POST['senha']);
$connect = mysql_connect('nome_do_servidor','nome_de_usuario','senha');
$db = mysql_select_db('nome_do_banco_de_dados');
$query_select = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'";
$select = mysql_query($query_select,$connect);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($select);
$logarray = $array['login'];


if($login == "" || $login == null){
echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('O campo login deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";

}else{
  if($logarray == $login){

    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse login já existe');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";
    die();

  }else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha) VALUES ('$login','$senha')";
    $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

    if($insert){
      echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='login.html'</script>";
    }else{
      echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse usuário');window.location.href='cadastro.html'</script>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Creio que falta informação. No código que você postou não mostra de onde vem o retorno "Usuário já existe."

Comment: A função `mysql_query()` já foi removida do php só para avisar.

Comment: A mensagem é "'Esse login já existe" (arrumei agora) no primeiro echo dentro do segundo if,

Comment: Coloque o código do `cadastro.html`, afinal é lá aonde o problema ocorre

Comment: Apenas para reforçar o que o @rray falou, as funções [`mysql_`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/) estão obsoletas e foram removidas no php 7, use [`mysqli_` ou `PDO`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/)

Comment: Bem-vindo Guilherme Geek, não deixe de var essa imagem  https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já foi dito as funções `mysql` estão obsoletas e foram removidas do PHP 7.

Utilize mysqli ou PDO, não vai doer nada, veja

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["login"])){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB");

    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'");

    $row = $result->fetch_row();


    if ($row[0] > 0) {

        //usuario existente, etc.....

    } else {


        $sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(login,senha) VALUES(?, ?)';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if(!$stmt){
            echo 'erro na consulta: '. $db->errno .' - '. $db->error;
        }

        $var1 = $login;
        $var2 = $senha;
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}

?>
```

Comment: o localhost seria o endereço do servidor? e o que seria o nome_db?

Comment: me desculpe, realmente sou novo nisso

Comment: @GuilhermeGeek, você tem um banco de dados? nome_db é o nome do banco de dados. Se você tem é só colocar o USUARIO, SENHA e o nome do banco em    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB"); localhost deixa como está. No Google tem a definição de localhost.

Comment: Mas meu banco de dados está em outro servidor, mesmo assim deixo localhost? pois coloquei o endereço do servidor. E o problema inicial persistiu, que é a mensagem "Esse login já existe" antes mesmo da exibição da página.

Comment: Não sei como isso funciona (banco de dados  em outro servidor). Nunca fiz uso dessa situação. Na pergunta isso não foi especificado. Faça outra pergunta relatando isso.

Comment: Desculpa, to falando bobagem. Deixei localhost e mesmo assim mesmo erro, a mensagem antes do formulário.